# Comparação entre uma string numérica e outra alfanumérica

Tags: php, string, representação-numérica

A seguinte operação retorna true:

```
var_dump("1" == "1e0"); //1 == 1 -> true
```

Porém se eu adicionar um "e" no fim da segunda string, já retorna false:

```
var_dump("1" == "1e0e"); //1 == 1 -> false???
```

Se fizer a seguinte operação, retorna 2:

```
echo (int)"1" + (int)"1e0e"; // 2
```

A minha questão é, porque a segunda operação retorna false se na terceira operação, estou convertendo os valores para inteiro e retorna 1 + 1, ou seja, na segunda operação a comparação deveria ser 1 == 1, não teria que retornar true?

Outra questão é, se estou comparando 2 strings, porque a primeira operação retorna true se são duas strings diferentes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`1e0` é a notação científica para o número `1`, pois significa 1 × 10<sup>0</sup>. E o [php converte](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) strings númericas em números para fazer a comparação.

```php
var_dump("1000" == "1e3"); //1000 == 1000 -> true 
var_dump("1" == "1e0"); //1 == 1 -> true
```

`1e0e` não é uma [notação válida](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota%C3%A7%C3%A3o_cient%C3%ADfica#Nota.C3.A7.C3.A3o_E) por isso:

```php
var_dump("1" == "1e0e"); //1 != da string "1e0e"
```

Sempre que fizer o casting verá que isso ocorre, pois o casting força a conversão em inteiro:

```php
var_dump((int)"1" == (int)"1e0e"); // true
```

Comment: Esse é um dos muitos inconvenientes do PHP. Esse "achismo", essa "intromissão" são grandes causadores de bugs difíceis de depurar.

Comment: Então, porque na função var_dump a string "1e0" é convertida para numérico mas o "1e0e" não? Não deveria converter para 1 como faz na primeira sem a necessidade do (int) antes da string?

Comment: @Felipe porque como já disse na resposta  `1e0e` não é uma notação [científica válida](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota%C3%A7%C3%A3o_cient%C3%ADfica#Nota.C3.A7.C3.A3o_E).

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Concordo, se eu estou comparando Maçãs com Laranjas, não é porque ambas são frutas que eu quero que elas retornem `true`.

Comment: Abençoado seja o polimorfismo proporcionado pelas *interfaces* \o/

Answer (score 8):

Para evitar a confusão na hora da comparação utilize `===` ao invés de `==`, assim além do conteúdo o PHP vai compara o tipo também.

```
var_dump("1" === "1e0"); // false
```

String `"1"` é diferente da string `"1e0"`

```
var_dump("1" === "1e0e"); // false
```

String `"1"` é diferente da string `"1e0e"`

```
var_dump((int)"1" == (int)"1e0e"); // true
```

Inteiro `1` é igual ao inteiro `1`

Answer (score 3):

Comparar `===` não resolve, veja que `0xFA` é 250, logo ( 250 === 0xFA ) resulta em `TRUE`

1) Comparar o tamanho de uma string para um input que seja: `0xFA`

```
if( $string <= 255 ) // 250 < 255 // Logo retornará TRUE
```

2) Converter para string causa o mesmo efeito:

```
( (string)255 === (string)0xFF )
```

---

<sub>**O seu exemplo:**</sub>

Aqui você tem uma comparação simples de string, `1e0e` não assume valor de inteiro e `1 == 1` não é a operação que ocorre.

```
var_dump("1" == "1e0e"); //1 == 1 -> false???
```

Aqui você tem `1e0e` como uma string e quando converte pata INT, naturalmente assume o valor de 1, que somado com 1 resulta em 2;

```
echo (int)"1" + (int)"1e0e"; // 2
```

---

Se você quer comparar de forma efetiva, terá que fazer uma combinação de verificações:
. Você pode forçar o input a assumir um valor de string com `(string)$input`
. Combinar `mb_strlen` para comparar o comprimento das entradas.

Se puder, de mais informação sobre o tipo de verificação.