# Por que no PHP a expressão "2 + '6 maçãs'" é igual a 8?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem, tipagem

Achei engraçado o exemplo, mas é válida a pergunta no sentido de entender o porquê de o PHP se comportar dessa forma.

Quando fazemos a soma exemplificada abaixo (uma inteiro somado a uma string):

```
$numero_macas = 2 + '6 maçãs';
```

O resultado é:

```
8
```

Porém nesse caso, ele retorna apenas `2`:

```
2 + 'seis(6) maçãs'
```

Por que o interpretador do PHP se comporta dessa forma?

Comment: Então se esta somando com string e não numeral, está saindo o resultado é bytes, cada letra vale 1 byte, e conte qt tem string ai são 8, e o seu nome Wallace tem 7 bytes.

Comment: @KingRider na verdade o que acontece é outra coisa. O PHP faz um cast implícito, similar ao val( ) de muitas linguagens. Ele lê a string digito por dígito, interpretando o valor numérico, e para ao encontrar um caractere não válido para número. Posteriormente o valor obtido é usado na soma.

Comment: Sim exato Bacco, cada linguagem diferente, sempre fazer obrigatório de converter de operador. Mas outro tipo php de PDO ai tem mais coisas diferente.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

O mecanismo de interpretação do PHP funciona da seguinte forma, caso a primeira parte da string seja um número válido ele é convertido(`int` ou `float`) e o resto é descartado, salvo algumas exceções como o sinal de mais (`+`), menos(`-`), ponto(`.`) e notações, cientifica (`e`) e hexadecimal (`x`), parece seguir o mesmo padrão de [filter_sanitize](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) para números.

No primeiro exemplo, depois do `6` tudo não é considerado um número válido.

```
$numero_macas = 2 + '6 maçãs';
                      ^
                      |
a partir daqui acabou o número
```

Exemplos curiosos:

```
<?php
//10 em notação cientifica, resultado 12
echo 2 + '10eNaN abacaxis'. PHP_EOL;

//26 em notação hexadecimal, resultado 28
echo  2 + '0x1A abacaxis'. PHP_EOL;

//sinal de menos, resultado -1
echo 2 + '-3 abacaxis'. PHP_EOL;

//sinal de mais, resultado -2
echo -5 + '+3 abacaxis'. PHP_EOL;

//sinal de menos com ponto, resultado 4.9
echo 5 + '-.1 abacaxis'. PHP_EOL;

//sinal de mais seguido de ponto, resultado -4.9
echo -5 + '+.1 abacaxis'. PHP_EOL;

//sinal de ponto, resultado 3.1
echo 3 + '.1 abacaxis'. PHP_EOL;
```

[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/mT9Qim)

Em alguns casos um número seguido de um letra pode ser um número válido como a notação cientifica, [essa é uma questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30382/91) bem interessante sobre o tema.

Caso a string inicie com um valor que não seja numérico ele não será convertido.

```
2 + 'seis(6) maçãs'
```

Answer (score 23):

Porque o PHP tenta fazer uma coerção de tipo em operações de tipos diferentes.

Quando ele tenta converter o primeiro, ele encontra um algarismo no texto e consegue converter para número, depois que ele encontra caracteres que não são algarismos (ou símbolo numérico válido na posição) ele descarta todo o resto.

No segundo caso ele já encontra caracteres inválidos de cara e descarta tudo, portando o número encontrado no texto é `0`.

O ideal é não confiar em dados *string* para conversão automática. É melhor validar antes de fazer a operação.

Answer (score 6):

O interpretador converte automaticamente a `string` iniciada por `6` no número `6.66` e `'66'` e `'66 abacates'` serão todos interpretados, na instrução numérica, como 66.

Answer (score 4):

Isso ocorre porque o PHP cria um `cast` automático da string para `int` ou `float`

Vejamos esse exemplo:

```
echo (float) '120.5 por cento de aumento da conta de luz';
```

Resultado

```
120.5
```