# Como adicionar ou subtrair um algarismo na TextBox por meio de um botão?

Tags: c#, .net, string, winforms, textbox

Quero adicionar a um número em um `TextBox` gerando um algarismo quando o usuário clicar no botão " + " e subtrair quando clicar no " - ". Por exemplo: o número aleatório foi 2. Se eu clicar no +, aparece 3. Se eu clicar em -, aparece o 1.

Pelo que parece, não se pode fazer operações tipo adição e subtração com `TextBox`es, como nesse código aqui, que foi apresentado o erro CS00019:

```
private void btn_plus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
resultado.Text = resultado + 1;
}
```

Onde o `resultado.Text` é o número convertido em *string* e `resultado` o nome da minha `TextBox`.

Como eu poderia fazer isso funcionar?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

Use o [`TryParse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__) se não quiser que gere um erro se o valor for inválido. Você pode tratar como desejar se for inválido. Neste caso eu ignorei a soma.

```
private void btn_plus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int numero;
    if (int.TryParse(resultado.Text, out numero)) {
        resultado.Text = (numero + 1).ToString();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JsZgUJ). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iIl6ey). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/Change.cs). Tive que adaptar já que não estou em uma aplicação WinForms.

Só use o `Parse()` ([diferença](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101)) quando quer que ele gere uma exceção se não conseguir *parsear* o número, o que não é comum querer isto. É melhor saber que deu erro e tratar ali mesmo sem o custo da exceção, ainda mais que a maioria dos programadores tratam exceções de forma errada.

Comment: Uma pergunta... O C# não dá erro ali, a variável `numero` foi declarada, mas não recebeu nenhum valor..?

Comment: @KaduAmaral eu tinha visto um erro no seu também e no fim na correria o que eu ia consertar eu não consertei no meu, agora está ok. Não porque o `TryParse` vai jogar um valor para ele. Há até uma possibilidade de poder declarar assim: `Int32.TryParse(resultado.Text, out int numero)` economizando uma linha. Claro que ele só joga se conseguir dar o *parse*, mas se não conseguir, não vai usar a variável. E no fundo tem um valor 0.

Comment: Ahh entendi. A saída do _parse_ vai para a variável `numero`, certo? Eu só tô especulando porque também estou estudando C# e não conhecia o método `TryParse`... :D

Comment: @KaduAmaral ele é melhor em 99% das vezes. Eu só esqueci de dizer ali em cima que essa sintaxe de declarar a variável dentro da chamada do método é algo que quase entrou no C# 6 e tem chance de entrar no C# 7.

Comment: O que é o erro que tu tinha visto no meu? É necessário converter valor pra _string_ pra atribuir ao _TextBox_?

Comment: @KaduAmaral isso mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

O C# não é como [o PHP que realiza operações com o que tiver pela frente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80767/8493), ele precisa trabalhar com tipos determinados, e como você mesmo expressou o valor do campo TextBox é texto (ou *string*). Para trabalhar com operações matemáticas primeiro é necessário converter o valor para algum tipo numérico como [Int](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/b3h1hf19(v=VS.110).aspx), [Float](https://stackoverflow.com/a/147811/3497987) e etc...

Então seu código ficaria...:

Para Somar:

```
resultado.Text = (int.Parse(resultado.Text) + 1).ToString();
```

Ou para Subtrair:

```
resultado.Text = (int.Parse(resultado.Text) - 1).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void btn_plus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    int boxI = resultado.Text        
    resultado.Text = boxI + 1;
}
```

Não tive tempo para testar, mas deve funcionar.

Comment: Caso de erro na quarta linha, converta para string o boxI.