# Alterando informações do cliente através do ID

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, asp.net, microsoft-access, conversão-de-tipo

Não consigo alterar as informações do cliente através do ID [image: tela do sistema]

Código que faz as alterações no Banco de dados

```
         public void Atualizar(Contato contato)//metodo para atualizar dados: update   
    {
        OleDbParameter[] parametros = {
            new OleDbParameter("CODIGO", contato.Codigo),
            new OleDbParameter("NOME", contato.Nome),
            new OleDbParameter("FONE", contato.Fone),
            new OleDbParameter("EMAIL", contato.Email)
        };
        new ConexaoDAL().ConexaoAuto(parametros, "update Contato set NOME=@NOME,EMAIL=@EMAIL,FONE=@FONE  where CODIGO=@CODIGO ", "Erro ao atualizar ");
    }
```

Evento Click da pagina

```
      public void SalvaDados()
    {
        try
        {
            if (SalvarCodigo == null)
            {
                Crud d = new Crud();
                d.Gravar(new Contato(SalvarNome.Text, SalvarFone.Text, SalvarEmail.Text)); // gravando pessoa 
                Message.Text = "Cadastro salvo com sucesso";
            }
            else
            {
                int codigo = Convert.ToInt32(SalvarCodigo);

                Crud d = new Crud();
                d.Atualizar(new Contato(codigo, SalvarNome.Text, SalvarFone.Text, SalvarEmail.Text));
                Message.Text = "Cadastro alterado com sucesso";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception(Message.Text = ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

[image: Exceção gerada]
OBS: quando da o erro ele fala para converter, mas já tentei converter o que esta dentro da textBox e mesmo assim nao funciona.
.aspx 
[image: Código ASP.Net]

Comment: Qual é o erro? Onde ocorre? Em que situação? Como não sei o problema, não sei nem se o que foi postado é suficiente para que possamos ajudar. A impressão que dá é que não é. Tira esse `try-catch` que ele não está fazendo nada útil aí, pleo contrário, está causado problema.

Comment: o erro ocorre quando eu insiro no campo codigo o codigo para ser alterado ele fala que tem que converter, mas mesmo convertendo aparece o mesmo erro.

Comment: A primeira coisa a fazer é tirar o `try-catch` conforme eu falei para ver o erro real, você está escondendo ele sem resolvê-lo. Não capture exceção se não pode resolver o problemas. Não capture `Exception` nunca, na não ser que saiba porque está fazendo isso. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101+%5Bexception%5D. Onde está `SalvarCodigo`? Eu acho esse código todo muito estranho, parece haver um problema geral de *design*.

Comment: Entendo, já to tirando o try-catch, o SalvarCod esta vindo da pagina, aonde insiro o cod do cliente.

Comment: Mas mostre ele pra gente poder ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

O código todo me parece estranho e parece haver problemas de *design* nele. Pode ser uma questão de estilo e gosto, mas eu faria todo o método `SalvarDados()` em apenas 2 linhas. Não vou tentar ensinar dessa forma porque pode confundir quem não tem uma boa noção geral. Eu acho estranho criar uma instância de `Crud` só para isso, mas sei que tem quem goste disso. Oque certamente é um um erro é ter esse `try-catch`. Ele não está resolvendo problema algum. Na verdade está dificultando identificar o erro. Mesmo que tivesse que capturar uma exceção, [não deveria ser `Exception`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/101).

Você não deve converter dados que você não tem controle. Deve usar `TryParse()` ou algo parecido, se falhar tem como se recuperar no fluxo normal da aplicação. Isso pode ser visto [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82477/101) e [nessa também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129410/101). Veja [Diferenças entre Parse() vs TryParse()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101) e [Qual a principal diferença entre int.Parse() e Convert.ToInt32()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90981/101). Se falhar você deve tomar alguma atitude, mas não pode salvar os dados. O problema pode estar aí.

Mas nem adianta tentar converter algo que não pode ser convertido. Oque talvez deva fazer é:

```
if (int.TryParse(SalvarCodigo.Text, var out codigo)) { //<=======note o .Text aqui
    var d = new Crud();
    d.Atualizar(new Contato(codigo, SalvarNome.Text, SalvarFone.Text, SalvarEmail.Text));
    Message.Text = "Cadastro alterado com sucesso";
} else {
    //aqui trata se o código é inválido
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/TryParse2.cs).

Tenho dúvidas e não tem outros problemas.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas dicas e ajudas funcionou aqui! Obg

Comment: @AndréFelipeJardimFirmo dê uma olhada no [tour] para entender como o site funciona.

Comment: Pode deixar vou ler com calma, peço desculpas pelo ocorrido

Comment: @AndréFelipeJardimFirmo A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.