# O que faz a expressão "'2 porcos' + '3 cavalos' == '5 animais'" retornar true em PHP?

Tags: php, operadores, conversão-de-tipo

Já fiz uma pergunta parecida aqui no StackOverlow em: [Por que no PHP a expressão "2 + '6 maçãs'" é igual a 8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80767/por-que-no-php-a-express%C3%A3o-2-6-ma%C3%A7%C3%A3s-%C3%A9-igual-a-8)

Porém, dando uma olhada em algumas <del>coisas estranhas</del> curiosidades que existe no PHP, vi que a seguinte expressão retorna `true`.

```
var_dump('2 porcos' + '3 cavalos' == '5 animais'); // bool(true)
```

Eu até concordo que no PHP, a expressão `"2 porcos" + "3 cavalos"` retornará `int(5)`, por conta da conversão das strings numéricas iniciais para o tipo `int`.

Mas por que a comparação retorna `true`, já que o conteúdo é completamente diferente?

É certo que `==` compara somente os valores, porém vemos nitidamente que os valores não são iguais.

Concordo que o exemplo abaixo esteja correto:

```
var_dump('2 porcos' +  '3 cavalos' == 5); // bool(true)
```

Porém, essa expressão não teria que retornar  `false`?

```
var_dump(5 == '5 animais'); // bool(true)
```

E mais questionável ainda:

```
var_dump(5 == '00005 animais'); // bool(true);
```

É claro que ao fazermos a conversão, `"00005 animais"` retorna `5`, mas por que isso é válido em termos de comparação? Isso é ruim.

Notei também que no php `5 == '5 cãezinhos'` retorna `true`.

E isso pode ser um problema pra quem não conhece essas "curiosidades" da linguagem.

Veja alguns exemplos abaixo

```
5 == '5 cavalos'; // true
'5' == '5 cavalos'; false
'5' == 5; // true
'5 ' == 5; // true
' 5' == 5; // true
```

Peguntas:

- O PHP **sempre** converte os valores para depois compará-los?
- Quando é que posso confiar no operação de comparação (`==`) e quando posso confiar apenas no operador de idênticos (`===`)?

Comment: Não sei o principio utilizado para a comparação no PHP, talvez se deva ao fato do objetivo inicial da linguagem.
Mas, vai aí a confusão ainda maior na explicação -> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/types.comparisons.php O que eu faço é sempre utilizar === para ter certeza.

Comment: `'5 ' == 5 // true`

Comment: As respostas da pergunta anterior já foram suficientemente esclarecedoras, se você quer levar em consideração o tipo use `===`

Comment: `var_dump('5 ' == 5);` da false?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters os operadores não são a mesma coisa, mas a resposta é a mesma. A questão não é os operadores e sim como o PHP trabalha com os dados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O PHP sempre faz cast dos valores para booleanos por padrão, então em algumas instruções onde você acredita estar comparando números por exemplo, o PHP está comparando booleanos. Duas coisas importantes são a ordem das expressões e o operador de comparação.

Nos exemplos da pergunta foi usado apenas o de igual(`==`) ele compara apenas  os valores e descarta o tipo(int, bool, string etc).

```
5 == '5 cavalos'; comparação entre ints
'5' == '5 cavalos'; false pq é uma comparação entre strings
'5' == 5; // true, comparação entre ints 
'5 ' == 5; // true, mesma coisa
```

`==` deve ser usado quando apenas o valor importar idependente do tipo.
`===` deve ser usando quando o valor e o tipo da variável importaram.

```
<?php
//O PHP entende isso como comparação entre booleanos, logo imprime 1(true)
//    1     ==   1
if((bool)-1 == 100){
    echo true;
}else{
    echo false;
}

//Comparação entre um bool e int, retorna 0(false) pois os tipos não os mesmos
//    1      ===  1      
if((bool)100 === 100){
    echo true;
}else{
    echo (int)false;
}
//Comparação entre o mesmo valor e tipo, logo é true
// 100 === 100
if(100 === 100){
    echo true;
}else{
    echo (int)false;
}
```

Saída: `101`

Obs: <sub>Usei `echo (int)false;` para imprimir zero nos exemplos, sem o cast não imprime nada.</sub>

Comment: E no caso de `' 5' == 5`? Isso é estranho

Comment: @WallaceMaxters É estranho ser true?

Comment: Pois é, seria uma ótima discussão se não fosse fechada. Mas fazer o que né? Talvez ninguém nem tenha aberto o console pra testar :)

Comment: retorna true sim @rray

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, veja se esse código vai dar um false e o outro true.
`echo var_dump(' 5' == 5);
echo '<br>';
echo var_dump(' 5' == 5);` lol vc precisa copiar.

Comment: Os dois deram `true`. Com eu havia dito, @rray

Comment: Lembro uma vez q vi uma questão de certificação q fazia uma comparação com `==` e tinha as expressões numa ordem especifica :P dava um resultado bombastico ... se eu conseguisse achar ... ia dar pra exemplicar bem quando a ordem do cast e da comparação fazem diferença. @WallaceMaxters

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, acho ele convertou errado o primeiro exemplo, faz o seguinte remova o espaço, no lugar faça, segure o `alt`e aperte `255` e rode novamente hehe.

Answer (score 3):

```
var_dump(5 == '5 animais'); // bool(true)
E mais questionável ainda:

var_dump(5 == '00005 animais'); // bool(true);
```

Porque que isto haveria de retornar false?
Isto tem a ver com os mecanismos do PHP ele "procura" os valores que permitem fazer este calculo. E por isto é que PHP é uma má linguagem porque permite a maior parte dos erros apenas apresentado warnings. É uma linguagem desleixada... Tal como if($x = 5) torna-se verdadeiro porque x assume o valor de 5. Muitas das vezes pequenos promenores como estes tornam-se bugs, o PHP é desleixado e permite muita coisa que não devia.

Se amanhã começares a programar em C++ vais ver o que acontece.

Voltando ao assunto, tendo em conta que 00005 é equivalente a 5 em qualquer lado do mundo é mais que justificavel o facto de ser verdadeira essa validação.

0 a esquerda não conta para nada, a direita já é outra conversa :)

Se fosse: var_dump(5 == '50000 animais') já teria que dar false.

Espero ter esclarecido algo. E relembro, no que toca a PHP temos que ter muito cuidado porque é muito facil desleixarmos e perdemos as nossas boas maneiras de programar.

Um grande abraço.

**EDIT:**

Em relação ao == e ao ===.

== quer dizer igual.

=== quer dizer estritamente igual. Ou seja, haja o minimo de diferença e já ira ser falsa a validação.

Eu uso === quando recebo parametros nas minhas classes.

**Exemplo:**

```
public function teste($table=false)
{
     if($table === false) return false;
}
```

Comment: No javascript isso retornaria `false`: `5 == '5 pratas'`. E ainda pergunta por que teria que retornar `false`? A pergunta na verdade é: _Por que no PHP retorna o que outras linguagens não retornam_?

Comment: Vou voltar a repetir. O PHP é uma linguagem desleixada. Vai sempre tentar mostrar-te um resultado, falso ou verdadeiro, ele vai sempre tentar alcançar um resultado. O javascript não faz isso. Aliás, mal ele detecta um erro, seja o que for, para a execução de javascript e muitas das vezes para da pagina toda.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua colocação @Wilson. Apesar de alguns pensarem que se trata de opnião (e apesar de gostar muito do PHP), concordo que o mesmo seja desleixado em alguns (quero dizer muitos) pontos.

Comment: Ora essa, fico feliz por ter sido útil. Qualquer coisa vou andar por aqui. Abraço

Comment: o interessante é que o próprio [Manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/types.comparisons.php) chama a comparação com `==` de **Comparações frouxas com ==**

Comment: É normal, porque aqui voltamos ao que eu disse. Estritamente igual, ou seja, tem que ser mesmo igual caso contrario irá ser falso. Mas sim, sem duvida que o melhor a fazer é ler a documentação e assim aprende-se bastante :)

Comment: `<?php
$n = 25;
$n1 = 031;
if($n === $n1) echo true;` pq esse código da true :P hehe. +1 pela resposta.

Answer (score 2):

```
var_dump('2 porcos' + '3 cavalos' == '5 animais'); // bool(true)
```

Quando somamos um número com uma string em PHP, ele tenta converter a string em número e depois soma os 2, conforme [Concatenação e Operações Matemáticas](http://www.tiexpert.net/programacao/web/php/concatenacao-e-operacoes-matematicas.php).

E de acordo com [Operadores de Comparação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php),

> Se você comparar um inteiro com uma string, a string é convertida para
>   um número.

Por isso, ao executar `'2 porcos' + '3 cavalos' == '5 animais'` o resultado é `2+3 == 5`  `5==5` `true`

Comment: _Eu converti_? Ou o PHP converteu? Eu só queria saber se `5 == '00005 cavalos'`!

Comment: o PHP converteu! estou dizendo que na sua pergunta voce esqueceu de converter o '5 animais' para 5...

Comment: para comparar os valores ele converte as 2 expressoes para o mesmo tipo... como 5 é inteiro.. ele tenta converter '0005 cavalos' para inteiro.. que da 5 também

Comment: Eu "não esqueci". na verdade a pergunta é exatamente sobre isso. Não é um problema que estou enfrentando ou uma dúvida. Quero saber por que é que isso acontece. '3 galinhas' + '3 patos' == '6 aves' é correto. Mas eu estou pedindo para o PHP comparar e não pra converter nada. Eu quero saber qual é o dessa comparaçaõ.

Comment: ok vou editar aqui com base em pesquisas