# Formar número para valor em PHP

Tags: php

Tenho uma variável com um valor em formato de string:

```
15000
```

Preciso comparar esse valor com outro no banco de dados. Acontece que nessa string que vem com o valor, os dois últimos dígitos são sempre referentes aos centavos. Ou seja, o valor acima é 150.00

Como posso formatar o valor?

Ex: variável com valor de 124589 = 1245.89

Comment: Não é só dividir por 100? https://ideone.com/quSxQ8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta dividir por 100:

```
$resultado = "1234589" / 100;  // 12345.89
```

Isso será um número em ponto flutuante, mas caso necessite, seja lá por qual razão, que isso seja uma *string*, basta fazer o *cast*:

```
$resultado = (string) ("1234589" / 100);  // "12345.89"
```

Mas, **cuidado**, se sua *string* não for numérica, dependendo das configurações do seu PHP, o resultado pode ser inesperado:

```
$resultado = "batatas" / 100;  // 0
```

Leia mais em [Por que no PHP a expressão "2 + '6 maçãs'" é igual a 8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80767/5878)

Comment: Se for necessário converter o valor para numérico: `$resultado = floatval("1234589" / 100);  // 12345.89`

Comment: @RodrigoTognin o resultado da divisão já será numérico, não precisa fazer a conversão.

Comment: Certo, então pode retirar o `(string)`, pois você estaria forçando a variável para string em vez de numérico

Comment: @RodrigoTognin acho que vc pulou essa parte: "mas caso necessite, seja lá por qual razão, que isso seja uma string, basta fazer o cast:" (ou talvez eu não tenha entendido onde quer chegar)

Comment: @Bacco A minha intenção era forçar o número para float, porque eu não sabia que o simples fato de dividir uma string por um número já retornada float. A minha intenção era ter a certeza de que o resultado da divisão seria float. Foi uma inocência minha.

Comment: @RodrigoTognin entendi. O PHP tem uma coerção de tipo automática mesmo (como vc já percebeu). Nesse ponto ele é menos "maluco" que o JS, que usa umas regras meio complexas.

Comment: @RodrigoTognin Para operadores matemáticos, o PHP irá tratar os operandos como numéricos. Por trás dos panos, o que acontece é que a *string* primeiro é avaliada como numérico para depois efetuar a divisão, tanto que `"10" / "2"` irá retornar `int(5)`. O link que adicionei ao final da resposta trata sobre isso, caso queira ler mais.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Legal! Vou dar uma olhada. Obrigado