# Qual a diferença entre parseInt() e operador + antes de uma string?

Tags: javascript, string, desempenho, operadores, conversão-de-tipo

Eu vi um colega convertendo uma *string* para inteiro usando a sintaxe `var a = +"10"` porém eu sempre utilizei o `parseInt()` e a linha fica geralmente assim `var a = parseInt("10")`.

Por que ao colocar o operador `+` antes de uma *string* isso acontece? E qual a melhor recomendação: usar o `parseInt()` ou o operador? Tem alguma influência em performance?

Comment: O único conselho que posso dar que não está nas respostas é que use o 2º parâmetro do [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix) pra especificar a base da conversão se por algum acaso ou azar você tenha que dar suporte para IE8-

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaScript possui tipagem fraca, além de tipagem dinâmica. Isto significa que ela faz coerção de tipo para tentar atender o que o programador mandou fazer usando um critério de mais proximidade possível, então se o código tem um operador `+` mesmo tendo só uma *string* ele acha que quer uma operação matemática. Só decidiria que quer uma concatenação se tivessem duas *strings*.

Isto parece uma decisão errada e não muito intuitiva? Sim, por isso as pessoas não gostam de JS, é uma linguagem que tenta ajudar tanto que atrapalha. Tipagem fraca quase sempre é um erro.

Qual a solução para isso? Fazer o seu da melhor forma possível, evitar esses *corner cases*. Só porque funciona não quer dizer que deveria usar. Todo programador deveria saber disto. Enquanto alguém achar que testar e funcionar significa que está certo haverá código ruins por aí.

Quando quer converter uma *string* para um número use a função mais correta para isto, e ela é `parseInt()`. Dá clareza que é isso que deseja, não é um acidente.

Precisa medir (em cada navegador, cada versão) para ver se um dá mais performance que outro, mas não importa e não deve dar, pelo menos nada significativo porque ambos precisarão fazer um algoritmo relativamente complexo para atingir o objetivo, nenhum é miraculosamente simples e o outro muito complicado, em essência fará a mesma coisa.

Eu sou favorável até a linguagem ter um modo *strict* mais rígido que possa ligar um limitador para este tipo de coisa e obrigar usar o mais certo. Melhor ainda, oficializar TypeScript porque as pessoas estão usando JS para fazer sistemas, uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica e fraca não funciona mais.

[image: JS Good Partes Vs Definitive Guide]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado Maniero, você esclareceu minhas dúvidas!

Comment: Isso não é corner case, é outro operador.

Answer (score 6):

A primeira sintaxe utiliza operador unário **+**, que converte a variável para Number.

Como sua pergunta é sobre a diferença, utilizando a função `parseInt` ele também vai converter para Number mas vai truncar qualquer casa decimal que essa variável possua para essa variável se tornar um Number do tipo inteiro.

Então se seu objetivo é transformar uma string num número inteiro a função `parseInt` é mais segura, mas se você quer apenas converter a string para Number a primeira sintaxe é mais sucinta.

Exemplo:

```js
var numero = "7.5"
console.log(+numero) // 7.5
console.log(parseInt(numero)) // 7
```

Comment: Para numeros decimais existe o `parseFloat()`, só adicionando à sua resposta.

Answer (score 2):

O tipo de dados em uma expressão pode confundir algumas operações de script se os componentes esperados da operação não forem do tipo certo. O JavaScript tenta ao máximo realizar conversões internas para evitar tais problemas, mas ela não pode ler sua mente. Se suas intenções forem diferentes do modo como o JavaScript trata os valores, então não obterá os resultados que esperava.

Um caso particularmente interessnte é a soma de números que podem estar no formato de strings de texto. Em uma instrução aritmética simples, que soma dois numeros, você recebe o resultado esperado:

```js
var soma = 3+3;

console.log(soma);
```

Mas se um desses números for string, o JavaScript terá a tendencia de converter o outro valor para uma string - transformando a ação do sinal mais de soma aritmética para associação de strings (ou concatenação). Portanto, na instrução `3+"3"` a força da string no segundo valor prevalece em relação à operação inteira. O primeiro valor é automaticamente convertido para string, e o resultado associa as duas strings.

```js
var soma = 3+"3";

console.log(soma);
```

Veja o que acontece quando outro numero é acrescentado à instrução: `3 + 3 + "3"`

```js
var soma = 3 + 3 + "3";

console.log(soma);
```

Há uma lógica por trás desse resultado. A expressão é avaliada da esquerda para a direita. A primeira operação de mais trabalha sobre dois números, gerando o valor 6. Mas, quando o 6 está para ser somado ao "3", o JavaScript permite que a força da string "3" predomine. O 6 é convertido para string e os dois valores são concatenados resultando o 63.

> Repare que nesses casos o operador `+` antes de strings não converteram a string para inteiro!

Se um valor numerico for armazenado como string, seus scripts terão dificuldades para aplicar esse valor a uma operação matemática. A linguagem JavaScript oferece duas funções internas para converter representações de string de numeros em numeros verdadeiros: parsInt() e parseFloat().

### CONCLUSÃO

a função correta a ser usada é `parseInt()`

```js
var soma = 3 + 3 + parseInt("3");

console.log(soma);
```

Comment: Mas nesse caso, se fosse usar o `+` para converter, ele não usaria: `3 + 3 + +"3"`?

Comment: @fernandosavio, quem vai saber se sabem?

Answer (score 2):

Complementando as outras respostas: quando a string contém um número inteiro (como `'123'`, `'42'`, etc), não há diferença no resultado. Mas quando a string não é exatamente um número inteiro, os resultados podem ser diferentes. Por exemplo:

```js
['', '     ', '\n', '7.5', '1x', '1.2.3', '3e2', 'xyz'].forEach(s => {
    console.log(`+"${s}" = ${+s} - parseInt("${s}") = ${parseInt(s)}`);
});
```

Desses, somente a string `'xyz'` dá o mesmo resultado para ambos os casos. As demais não:

```
+"" = 0 - parseInt("") = NaN
+"     " = 0 - parseInt("     ") = NaN
+"
" = 0 - parseInt("
") = NaN
+"7.5" = 7.5 - parseInt("7.5") = 7
+"1x" = NaN - parseInt("1x") = 1
+"1.2.3" = NaN - parseInt("1.2.3") = 1
+"3e2" = 300 - parseInt("3e2") = 3
+"xyz" = NaN - parseInt("xyz") = NaN
```

Para string vazia, string contendo vários espaços e string contendo quebra de linha (`\n`), a conversão com [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) retorna zero, e [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) retorna [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN).

Para uma string que representa um *float*, `+` dá o mesmo resultado de [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) e mantém as casas após a vírgula, retornando `7.5`. Já `parseInt` remove as casas decimais e retorna `7`.

Para `'1x'`, o `+` retorna `NaN`, enquanto `parseInt` retorna `1`. Isso acontece porque [segundo a especificação](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-unary-plus-operator) o operador unário `+`, quando aplicado a strings, usa o [algoritmo descrito aqui](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-tonumber-applied-to-the-string-type) (que basicamente não reconhece o caractere `x` e por isso falha e retorna `NaN`). Já `parseInt` usa um [algoritmo diferente](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Description): ele vai lendo os dígitos e quando encontra algo que não é um dígito válido, ignora o restante da string e converte os dígitos que leu até o momento, e por isso o retorno é `1` (similar [ao que o PHP faz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80767/112052)). O mesmo acontece para `'1.2.3'`, que retorna `NaN` com o operador `+`, mas retorna `1` com `parseInt`.

Já um número em notação científica (`'3e2'`) é reconhecido corretamente por `+`, que retorna `300`. Mas `parseInt` não reconhece este formato e retorna `3` (pelo motivo já descrito no parágrafo anterior). Nesse caso, você poderia usar `parseFloat('3e2')`, que retorna `300`.

Por fim, para a string `'xyz'`, ambos retornam `NaN`.

Vale lembrar também que há algumas situações bizarras que podem ocorrer se você passa números em vez de strings para `parseInt`:

```js
console.log(parseInt(0.0000005)); // 5
console.log(parseInt(1000000000000000000000)); // 1

// com o "+" isso não ocorre
// obs: os valores ficam corretos, mas a saída estará em notação científica
console.log(+0.0000005); // 5e-7
console.log(+1000000000000000000000); // 1e+21
```

Achou estranho? A explicação está [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/506307/112052).

---

[Nesta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17106702) tem uma tabela comparativa bem completa, com mais casos e os respectivos resultados para cada conversão. Nesse mesmo *link* há outras respostas que citam outras diferenças e *corner cases*.

<sup>*Testes feitos no Firefox 68.0.2 e Chrome 76.0.3809.132 (ambos para Windows 64 bits).*</sup>