# Calculadora de Potência em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando realizar uma calculadora de potência, porém sempre retorna o resultado com `0` e não sei onde está o erro de lógica. Já refiz o código algumas vezes com mais ou menos linhas.

```
var numero, potencia;
var resultado = 0;


function ColetarInformacoes(){

    numero = prompt("Qual número será elevado ?");
    numero = parseInt(numero);

    potencia = prompt(" Elevado á qual potência ? ");
    potencia = parseInt(potencia);

    ValidarInformacoes();

}

function ValidarInformacoes(){

    if(numero  !== undefined || potencia !== undefined){
        throw new Error("Não aceitamos valores undefined...");
    }

    if(numero < 0){
        throw new Error("Calcula somente números positivos..."); 
    }

    if(isNaN(numero) || isNaN(potencia)){
        throw new Error("Os valores inseridos não são válidos...");
    }

}

function Calcular(){

    ColetarInformacoes();

    for(var i = 0; i < potencia; i++){
        resultado *= numero;
     }

    alert("O resultado é "+ resultado);
}
```

Comment: Seu codigo tem erros de lógica.  if(numero  === undefined || potencia === undefined)

Comment: Você deve mudar essa parte para coloca pra verifica se é totalmente undefined

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<sup>*Estou assumindo que é um exercício (ou um código para treinar), já que para calcular potências, é melhor usar [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow), conforme sugerido [na outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/412610/112052) (inclusive, ele trata outros casos que o seu código não, mas veremos isso em detalhes mais abaixo).*</sup>

---

O problema é que sua variável `resultado` começa com o valor zero. Então ao chegar nesse *loop*:

```
for (var i = 0; i < potencia; i++){
    resultado *= numero;
}
```

Você estará multiplicando o número por zero várias vezes, e o resultado será zero (*uma dica é fazer o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/112052), que erros como esse são descobertos rapidamente*).

Para corrigir é simples, basta inicializar `resultado` com 1 (que é o [elemento neutro da multiplicação](https://pt-pt.khanacademy.org/math/pre-algebra/pre-algebra-arith-prop/pre-algebra-arithmetic-properties/v/identity-property-of-1)).

Outro detalhe é que na validação você estava fazendo:

```
if(numero !== undefined || potencia !== undefined){
    throw new Error("Não aceitamos valores undefined...");
}
```

Ou seja, se `numero` **não** for `undefined`, ou se `potencia` **não** for `undefined`, dá erro. Mas o certo seria verificar se eles são `undefined`, usando `===` em vez de `!==`.

Mas na verdade você não precisa desse `if`, pois anteriormente já foi usado [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) para transformar o texto digitado em número, então as variáveis não serão `undefined`. Se a pessoa não digitar um número válido, `parseInt` retorna [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN), então basta verificar isso (aliás, é melhor verificar se é `NaN` **antes** de ver se o valor é zero, pois não faz sentido testar se o valor é menor que zero se é `NaN`).

Você também poderia evitar variáveis globais e fazer a função que lê os dados retornar os números lidos.

O código ficaria assim:

```js
function lerDados(){
    let numero = parseInt(prompt("Qual número será elevado?"));
    let potencia = parseInt(prompt("Elevado a qual potência?"));

    return validar(numero, potencia);
}

function validar(numero, potencia){
    // verifica antes se é NaN (não faz sentido testar se é < 0 antes de saber se é NaN)
    if (isNaN(numero) || isNaN(potencia)){
        throw new Error("Os valores inseridos não são válidos...");
    }

    if (numero < 0 || potencia < 0){
        throw new Error("Calcula somente números positivos..."); 
    }

    // retorna um array com os valores
    return [numero, potencia];
}

function calcular(){
    // obter os valores usando a sintaxe de destructuring assignment
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
    let [numero, potencia] = lerDados();
    let resultado = 1;

    for (let i = 0; i < potencia; i++){
        resultado *= numero;
    }

    alert("O resultado é "+ resultado);
}

calcular();
```

---

Repare também que usei `let` em vez de `var` para declarar as variáveis. Para saber a diferença, [veja esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/112052).

Também coloquei nas verificações se a potência é negativa (já que você não está calculando isso). Mas se quiser expoentes negativos, basta mudar o cálculo para:

```
if (potencia < 0) {
    potencia *= -1;
    numero = 1 / numero;
}
for (let i = 0; i < potencia; i++){
    resultado *= numero;
}
```

Por fim, não incluí uma verificação especial quando a base e o expoente são zero (já que [zero elevado a zero é indefinido](https://medium.com/however-mathematics/a-huge-conflict-what-is-zero-raised-to-the-power-of-zero-80298dc1995)). Mas se quiser, pode incluir:

```
if (numero === 0 && potencia === 0) {
    throw new Error("Zero elevado a zero é indefinido"); 
}
```

---

#### Sobre a conversão de string para número

[A outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/412610/112052) dizia ([antes de ser editada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/412610/4)) para usar `+` em vez de `parseInt` para converter o texto digitado para número. Embora o resultado seja o mesmo para números inteiros, [existem casos em que pode haver diferença](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/410229/112052)).

Por exemplo, se a pessoa digitar `2.5`, a conversão com `parseInt` resulta em `2`, enquanto com `+` resulta em `2.5`:

```js
let texto = "2.5";

console.log(parseInt(texto)); // 2
console.log(+texto); // 2.5
```

Para a **base**, não há problema ter um número com várias casas decimais, mas no seu caso, como você está fazendo um *loop* simples e multiplicando uma determinada quantidade de vezes, seu código não serve para **expoentes** com casas decimais.

Ou seja, seu código lidaria bem com `2.5` elevado a `3` (pois 2.5 seria multiplicado 3 vezes), mas não com `3` elevado a `2.5`, pois `parseInt` vai arredondar a potência para `2`.

Mas o pior é se você converter com `+`, pois nesse caso o `for` iria multiplicar 3 vezes:

```js
let numero = +"3";
let potencia = +"2.5";

let resultado = 1;
for (let i = 0; i < potencia; i++){
    resultado *= numero;
}
console.log(resultado); // 27
```

Como o `+` converte a string para 2.5, o `for` itera 3 vezes (já que na terceira iteração, ele compara `i < potencia`, e como `i` vale `2` e `potencia` vale `2.5`, ele faz uma iteração a mais do que deveria). Por isso o resultado é 27.

Sendo assim, para a **base**, não há problema em ter casas decimais, e você pode usar [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), que lê tanto números inteiros quanto com casas decimais. Já para o **expoente**, é melhor manter `parseInt` mesmo, já que seu código só lida com expoentes inteiros:

```
let numero = parseFloat(prompt("Qual número será elevado?"));
let potencia = parseInt(prompt("Elevado a qual potência?"));
```

Claro que você pode usar `+` em vez de `parseFloat` para ler a base, mas eu ainda prefiro usar as funções, cujos nomes deixam bem claro o que está acontecendo. [Um código mais claro e expressivo é melhor que um código mais curto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400495/112052) (e nesse caso nem é tão mais curto assim).

Se quiser considerar expoentes como `2.5`, aí é melhor usar `Math.pow` mesmo, que já sabe lidar com todos esses casos.

Tem ainda outro caso, que é quando o usuário só dá um <kbd>ENTER</kbd> no `prompt`. Nesse caso, a string será vazia, e usar `+` dá resultados diferentes de `parseInt` e `parseFloat`:

```js
let texto = "";

console.log(parseInt(texto)); // NaN
console.log(parseFloat(texto)); // NaN
console.log(+texto); // 0
```

`parseInt` e `parseFloat` retornam `NaN`, ou seja, se o usuário digitar uma string vazia, o código de validação dirá que as entradas são inválidas. Mas usar `+` retorna zero, então no fim ele considera que uma string vazia é uma entrada válida.

O mesmo vale para quando a string só tem espaços (`"   "`). Então usar um ou outro faz diferença sim, principalmente nesses *corner cases*, que você tem que decidir se vai considerar válidos ou não. Se você pede que o usuário digite alguma coisa, o código tem que estar preparado para validar essa coisa, e só prosseguir se os dados forem válidos.

Enfim, não troque um método por outro só porque é "mais curto", ou porque parece "mais legal". Saiba as implicações de cada um e use o que fizer mais sentido para o que você pretende fazer.

Answer (score 3):

## Solução:

1. Use o método `Math.pow` para cálculos de potência.
2. Quando você comparou se é `undefined`, você usou `!==` que é o operador de negação de tipo e de valor, mude para `==`.
3. A comparação se é undefined é inútil, pois quando mudar para número não fica em undefined, mas como NaN
4. Coloque o prompt dentro da função parseInt , pois e desnecessário recebe um número do prompt pra depois em outra linha mudar o tipo do valor para número.
5. Deixe essas váriaveis "numero,potencia e resultado" dentro da função e use o let(váriavel de escopo) para declarar o tipo de dado.
6. Se nenhuma das verificação dar true, ele retorna um valor(use if,else if, else).

```js
Calcular();


function ColetarInformacoes() {

  let numero = parseInt(prompt("Qual número será elevado ?"));

  let potencia = parseInt(prompt(" Elevado á qual potência ? "));

  return ValidarInformacoes(numero, potencia);
}

function ValidarInformacoes(numero, potencia) {

  if (numero < 0) {
    throw new Error("Calcula somente números positivos...");
  } else if (isNaN(numero) || isNaN(potencia)) {
    throw new Error("Os valores inseridos não são válidos...");
  } else {
    return [numero, potencia];
  }

}

function Calcular() {

  let [numero, potencia] = ColetarInformacoes();
  let resultado = Math.pow(numero, potencia)
  console.log("Valor é: " + resultado)
}
```

Comment: Existem casos em que o `+` dá resultados diferentes de `parseInt`, então eu não daria a sugestão para trocar sem justificativa e sem entender todas as implicações. Na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/412617/112052) eu mostro casos em que dá diferença :-)

Comment: Se sabe a diferença, poderia ter explicado na resposta. Se vc só diz para mudar, sem explicar o motivo, a pessoa pode entender que o outro jeito está errado (mas não está, apenas funciona de forma diferente em alguns casos). A ideia do Stack Overflow é que as respostas sejam úteis não só para quem perguntou, mas para qualquer um que visite o site futuramente, então é importante explicar essas coisas. Espero que entenda e não leve a mal meu comentário, foi uma crítica construtiva, para que a sua resposta (e o site com um todo) melhorem.

Comment: No item 2, além de não conter nenhuma explicação, supõe que o AP quer calcular a potência aceitando `float` como base e dá a entender que é a maneira correta de ser feita, quando é apenas diferente. Isso, e sua postura com o colega que tentou ajudar você a melhorar sua resposta, são as justificativas do meu _downvote_. De nada querido!

Comment: A edição resolveu o problema anterior, _downvote_ removido.