# Como funciona o operador "+" em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, tipagem, operadores, conversão-de-tipo

Recentemente eu tinha visto no site do [*MDN Web Docs*](https://developer.mozilla.org/) que dizia que era possível converter uma `String` em um `Number` que nem no exemplo abaixo:

```js
let n1 = "10";
console.log(typeof n1); //=> string ("10")
```

A variável `n1` possui o valor `"10"`, que é do tipo `string`. Mas, se tentar fazer isto:

```js
let n1 = "10";
console.log(typeof +n1) //=> number (10)
```

A variável `n1` passa a ter um valor do tipo `number`. O problema é que se, em vez de exibir o tipo da variável `n1`, e sim mostrar a conversão, a variável não é mais `number`, e sim `string`:

```js
let n1 = "10";
console.log(n1 + 10 + " " + typeof n1); // "1010" (string)
console.log(+n1 + 10 + " " + typeof n1) // "20" (tipo string)
```

Como isso é possível? No último exemplo ele retorna o tipo `string`, então era para concatenar `+n1 + 10` e dar o mesmo resultado do primeiro exemplo que é `1010`, mas não ele soma os dois valores e dá o resultado `20`, mas ele não se comporta como um valor do tipo `number` e sim um valor do tipo `string`.

Alguém por favor pode me explicar se isso isso é um bug ou eu que não entendi algo direito? Eu sei que existem outras formas de converter algo em determinadas coisas mas eu quero me focar nesse problema.

Comment: Sobre esses seus testes do final da pergunta, repare que as operações são avaliadas da esquerda para a direita. Então o primeiro caso começa com string + número, e a segunda com número + número.

Comment: Não diretamente relacionado, mas em alguns casos, usar `+` para converter string para número pode dar resultados diferentes de [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) e [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) (que são as funções que prefiro usar em vez de `+`). Veja mais detalhes em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/410229/112052

Answer (score 12):

Não é um bug. Isso é algo esperado da linguagem. O operador `+` está especificado de modo que pode atuar como um [operador unário](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-unary-plus-operator) ou como um [operador binário](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-addition-operator-plus).

## Operador `+` unário

Se estiver no contexto de **operador unário**, isto é, estiver operando sobre somente **um** valor, a sua *única* função é converter o [único] operando ao tipo primitivo `number`. Veja alguns exemplos:

```js
console.log(+ false); // 0
console.log(+ true); // 1
console.log(+ "10"); // 10
```

Quando atua como operador unário, o `+` atua de modo similar ao construtor `Number`, que, quando chamado como função, converte o primeiro argumento ao tipo numérico.

## Operador `+` binário

O `+` também pode fazer o papel de um **operador binário**. Nesse caso, opera sobre **dois** valores. Nesse sentido, o `+` pode ter duas funções diferentes, a depender do tipo dos dois operandos:

- Realizar a **soma** de dois valores (adição); ou:
- Realizar a **concatenação** de duas strings.

Para que isso aconteça, algumas regras são estabelecidas, de modo a estabelecer quando ocorrerá a adição dos valores ou a concatenação dos valores. Ocorre assim:

- Primeiro, o operador converte os dois operandos a valores primitivos. Após isso, irá seguir a um dos dois modos:

  1. **Modo string**: Se qualquer um dos dois operandos for uma string, o outro operando será convertido ao tipo `string` correspondente. Os dois valores serão posteriormente concatenados e retornados como string.
  2. **Modo numérico**: Caso contrário (nenhum dos operandos é string), converterá ambos os operadores ao tipo `number`. Os dois valores serão posteriormente somados e retornados como número.

Você pode ver isso funcionando abaixo:

```js
// Modo string (caso um dos operandos seja string):
console.log(1 + "5"); // "15"
console.log("5" + 1); // "51"
console.log(false + "y"); // "falsey"

console.log('---');

// Modo numérico (caso nenhum dos operandos seja string):
console.log(false + 1); // 1 (false será convertido para 0)
console.log(true + 1); // 2
console.log(5 + []); // 5 ([] é convertido para 0)
```

---

No último exemplo da pergunta, a avaliação dos operadores segue uma regra de precedência, que pode ser consultada [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table).

---

## Referência:

- *JavaScript for impatient programmers*, [§ 12.2](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_operators.html#the-plus-operator).

Comment: Toda vez que vejo um array sendo somado com alguma coisa eu lembro disso: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat