# Como funciona o toString no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

Eu queria muito entender para que serve e como usar o método `toString`, por que eu sempre procuro em sites e não consigo entender pelo jeito que eles estão falando e demonstrando, então se alguém puder me explicar para que esse método serve, bem como quais os modos de usá-lo vai me ajudar muito.

Tenho o código abaixo, mostrando o comando que aprendi por aulas por aí, mas não entendi o funcionamento do `toString`.

```js
/* Objetivo: Desenvolver um programa em JavaScript que faça a leitura de 2 números Inteiros
   aplique a conversão de valores com parseInt e apresente o resultado da soma entre eles.
   Entrada de Dados por Formulário. */

/* Definição de Variáveis */
var js_n1;
var js_n2;
var js_soma;

/* Definição da função soma() para capturar dados, processar somatória e apresentar o resultado */
function soma() {
    /* Entrada de Dados */
    js_n1 = parseInt(document.MeuFormulario.f_n1.value);
    js_n2 = parseInt(document.MeuFormulario.f_n2.value);

    /* Processamento de Dados */
    js_soma = js_n1 + js_n2;

    /* Saída de Dados */
    window.alert('Resultado da Somatória = ' + js_soma.toString());
}
```

```html
<h3>Somatória de dois números inteiros</h3>

<!-- Definição da área e dos elementos de um Formulário -->
<form name="MeuFormulario" action="" method="POST">
    Entre com o valor 1: <input type="text" name="f_n1"><p><p>
    Entre com o valor 2: <input type="text" name="f_n2"><p><p>
    <input type="button" name="btn_somar" value="Somar" onclick="soma()">
    <input type="reset" name="btn_apagar" value="Apagar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O `toString` é um método disponível em vários objetos do JavaScript. Possui um comportamento diferente dependendo do objeto o qual faz parte. No entanto, tem sempre o mesmo objetivo, isto é, criar uma representação em string do objeto que o chama.

No seu caso, o `toString` faz parte do protótipo de `Number`, e converte um número em string seguindo [esta especificação](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-number.prototype.tostring).

Ainda no seu exemplo em questão, chamar o `toString` em um número é desnecessário, uma vez que o operador `+` já irá fazer isso por você. Para saber mais sobre esse comportamento do operador `+`, leia [esta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/436573/69296).

```js
console.log('Exemplo ' + (1).toString());
console.log('Exemplo ' + 2);
```

No caso do [`Number.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString), um argumento `radix` pode ser informado para formar a representação do número em uma outra base numérica, como binária (se receber `2` no argumento *radix*), hexadecimal (se receber `16`), etc.

Por exemplo:

```js
const num = 123456;

// Quando não é informado um argumento radix, o padrão será 10.
console.log(num.toString()); // 123456
console.log(num.toString(10)); // 123456

// Valor mínimo do argumento radix (2):
console.log(num.toString(2)); // 11110001001000000

// Exemplo de converter um número para a sua representação em hexadecimal:
console.log(num.toString(16)); // 1e240

// Valor máximo do argumento radix (36):
console.log(num.toString(36)); // 2n9c
```

Comment: A qual "comentário" você se refere?

Comment: @x7MKDeath7x se você quer que ele apague a **resposta**, não é assim que o site funciona. Faça o [tour]

Comment: Não é bem assim (// Número `2` é convertido para string pelo operador `+`.). O que acontece é que se você soma uma string a um número, você converte o número em seu equivalente de string.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo, sim, está errado? Acima do código desse comentário, tem uma explicação mais detalhada. No fundo, quem é responsável pela conversão é o operador binário `+`.

Comment: eu só quis ajudar, o que dá a entender na frase é que se simplesmente colocar o sinal + antes do numero o converte em string.

Comment: Sim, eu entendo, obrigado. :) Eu removi aquele comentário do código, deixando somente a explicação (mais detalhada) acima dele.

Answer (score 0):

Bem, o método `toString()` converte valores no JavaScript para strings. No seu caso, retornaria o valor da somatória em [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). Pois o valor *original* é um [number](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossario/N%C3%BAmero).

## Exemplos

#### Usando um valor booleano

```js
const valor = true
console.log(valor.toString()) // Retorna: "true"
```

#### Usando em uma array

```js
const array = new Array("Olá", "mundo!")
console.log(array.toString()) // Retorna: "Olá mundo!"
```

#### Usando em números

```js
const numero  = 13
console.log(numero.toString()) //  Retorna: "13"
```

Saiba mais em [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)

**Até mais!**

Comment: `const array = new Array("Olá", "mundo!"); console.log(array.toString());` não retorna `"Olá mundo!"` esse código vai retornar `"Olá,mundo!"` onde será retornado o resultado da implementação método `toString()` para cada elemento do array separado por virgulas

Answer (score -2):

eu concordo com o colega, não faz já que possuo um inteiro que trazer um retorno como uma string, até porque o primeiro numero após uma string sempre será 0 que é um inteiro.

Bom, fiz um exemplo que acredito ser de fácil entendimento, espero que te ajude, assim como me ajudou.

```js
const valor = 11;// aqui está representado um valor inteiro.
console.log("Valor é do tipo: "+typeof(valor.toString()))+" ";//aqui o inteiro é retornado como string pelo toString.

if(typeof(valor.toString()) == "number"){//vamos consultar o  tipo de cada variável.
console.log("sim, valor é um numero inteiro");//é inteiro?
}else{
console.log("não, valor é uma string");//é string?
}
const valor2 = "11";// aqui é uma string com o texto 11. 
console.log("Valor2 é do tipo: "+typeof(valor2))+" ";

if(typeof(valor2) == "number"){
console.log("sim, valor2 é um numero inteiro");//é inteiro?
}else{
console.log("não, valor2 é uma string");//é string?
}

const valor3 = 11;// aqui está representado um valor inteiro.
console.log("Valor3 é do tipo: "+typeof(valor3))+ " ";

if(typeof(valor3) == "number"){
console.log("sim, valor3 é um numero inteiro");// é inteiro?
}else{
console.log("não, valor3 é uma string");//é string?
}
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A pergunta da página é *"Como funciona o toString no JavaScript?"* e você respondeu *"eu concordo com o colega, não faz já que possuo um inteiro que trazer um retorno como uma string, até porque o primeiro numero após uma string sempre será 0 que é um inteiro."*, não faz sentido. Acho que você se enganou, está pensando que esse site é um fórum, e saiu comentando comentando uma resposta paralela, quando na verdade somos um Q&A e todo que tem que se preocupar é pergunta da página.