# Math.random definindo valores mínimos e máximos diferentes de 0

Tags: javascript, conversão-de-tipo, random, números

Estou tentando setar o valor mínimo e o máximo, utilizando `Math.random() * (max - min) + min;`, por exemplo, informando na página HTMl o mínimo = 10 e o máximo = 20, mas os resultados são sempre entre 0 e 9 somente, ou seja, não está obedecendo o parâmetro informado.

Se eu definir os números no código, como por exemplo: `5 + (Math.random() * 15);`, os resultados são de 5 a 19, o que faz sentido, se considerar que seriam sorteados 15 números, começando do 5.

Mas preciso informar o valor mínimo e o valor máximo que deverão ser sorteados.

Tentei também usar `min + (Math.random() * max);`, ainda informando na página html o mínimo = 10 e o máximo = 20, os resultados são números começando com 10 e alternado os dois últimos dígitos de 0 a 19.. por exemplo, 1019,106,1015,103... e assim por diante, ainda não respeitando o parâmetro definido.

Alguém pode me ajudar? Onde estou errando?

Segue o código:

```js
function sortear(){
    var min = document.getElementById("minimo").value;
    var max = document.getElementById("maximo").value;
    
    var sorteio = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = sorteio;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Insira o valor mínimo:
    <input type="number" name="minimo" id="minimo">
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>
    Insira o valor máximo:
    <input type="number" name="maximo" id="maximo">
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <button onclick="sortear()">Sortear</button>
</div>
<div>
  <h1 id="resultado"></h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Isso está acontecendo porque você não está passando valores numéricos, mas sim `string`s que, em alguns casos (dado o comportamento coercitivo do JavaScript) serão convertidos, mas em outros, não.

Desse modo, como a propriedade `value` sempre retorna uma `string`, você deve, antes de utilizá-los, convertê-los para o tipo adequado:

```js
function sortear(){
    var min = parseInt(document.getElementById("minimo").value, 10);
    var max = parseInt(document.getElementById("maximo").value, 10);
    
    var sorteio = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = sorteio;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Insira o valor mínimo: <input type="number" name="minimo" id="minimo"></p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Insira o valor máximo: <input type="number" name="maximo" id="maximo"></p>
</div>
<div>
  <button onclick="sortear()">Sortear</button>
</div>
<div>
  <h1 id="resultado"></h1>
</div>
```

No caso, utilizamos o **[`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)** para realizar a conversão de `string` para `number`. Outras opções para essa conversão são o [construtor `Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) ou [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat). Você também pode utilizar o [operador unário `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus), mas eu pessoalmente não gosto dessa última opção.

Agora explicarei de fato o que estava acontecendo quando você utilizava os tipos incorretos. Primeiramente, precisamos analisar a expressão a ser interpretada pelo JavaScript:

> ```
> Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
> ```

Supondo que `max` seja `"15"` e `min` seja `"5"` (note que ambos são strings), podemos assumir o seguinte:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * ("15" - "5") + "5");
```

Primeiro, o JavaScript avaliará a subtração dentro dos parênteses, que dão preferência para essa avaliação. Como o operador `-`, no JavaScript, significa exclusivamente a subtração aritmética, os dois operandos são corretamente convertidos para o tipo `number` antes do operador realizar a subtração.

Uma vez que temos o resultado da subtração anterior (`10` — note que agora se trata de um número), efetuaremos a multiplicação com o valor retornado por `Math.random`, que também é um número.

Por fim, o produto será **concatenado** (`+`) com o valor de `min` (que era para ser uma soma). Isso acontece porque, no JavaScript, o operador binário `+` pode ter significados diferentes dependendo do tipo de seus operandos. Eu explico melhor sobre isso nesta pergunta: [Como funciona o operador “+” em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/436573/69296).

Então, mantendo os valores `max` e `min` como string, teremos a seguinte avaliação passo a passo:

1. `Math.floor(Math.random() * ("15" - "5") + "5");`
2. `Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + "5");`
3. `Math.floor(0.8879528248948558 * 10 + "5");` — assumindo que `Math.random` retorne `0.8879528248948558`.
4. `Math.floor(8.879528248948558 + "5");`
5. `Math.floor("8.8795282489485585");` — Note que o `"5"` foi concatenado ao final do produto.
6. `8` — `Math.floor`, de acordo com a especificação, converte o tipo para `number` automaticamente.

Portanto, como você pode perceber, essa coerção de tipos automática do JavaScript é deveras confusa e cheia de sutilezas que podem afetar a robustez do código. Portanto, é sempre ideal que você **converta os tipos** explicitamente para o valor numérico se quiser trabalhar com operações matemáticas.