# Como fazer uma soma em um loop for ou while?

Tags: javascript, loop, for, data, while

Eu preciso que x seja somado a 7 após o loop, mas não estou conseguindo, o código funciona perfeitamente se faço `x++`, existe alguma maneira de fazer essa soma com 7?

```
var x;
for (x = dtdia + 2; x <= 31; x+ 7) {
    console.log(x);
};
```

Explicando o contexto, eu quero salvar um evento semanalmente no banco de dados, então pensei em criar um loop que identifica o dia de hoje e o dia da semana que ocorrerá esse evento e somar com 7 até chegar ao dia 31. O código completo para entender melhor:

```
var dt = new Date();
var weekday = dt.getDay();
var dtdia = dt.getDate();
var diasem = document.getElementById('DiaSem').value;
var soma = weekday - diasem;

switch (soma) {
    case -1: // 1dia
        var x;
        for (x = dtdia + 1; x <= 31; x+ 7) {
            console.log(x);
        };
        break;
    case  -2: // 2dia
        var x;
        for (x = dtdia + 2; x <= 31; x+ 7) {
            console.log(x);
        };
        break;
};
```

Comment: Mas já que fazendo com com x++ o código funcionava podias pensar em colocar x=x+6; dentro do loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando `x++` funciona porque o operador `++` modifica o valor de `x`. Então se quiser somar 7, fazer apenas `x + 7` não funciona porque isso não modifica o valor de `x`. O certo é fazer `x += 7` ou `x = x + 7`:

```
for (x = dtdia + 1; x <= 31; x += 7)
    etc...
```

---

Mas na verdade isso não vai funcionar corretamente para o que você precisa. Por exemplo, e se o mês não tiver 31 dias e por acaso no `for` o valor de `x` for 31? O mesmo vale para fevereiro, se `x` for maior que 28 (ou 29 em anos bissextos), você vai imprimir 30 ou 31 como dias válidos?

Nesse caso seria melhor você ir atualizando o `Date`, e só imprimir se ainda estiver no mês atual:

```js
var dt = new Date(); // data atual
var mesAtual = dt.getMonth(); // mês atual

var diasem = 3; // quarta-feira (coloquei algum valor qualquer só de exemplo)

// pega a próxima quarta feira 
dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + (diasem + (7 - dt.getDay())) % 7);

// enquanto não mudar o mês
while (dt.getMonth() == mesAtual) {
    console.log(dt.getDate());
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 7); // soma 7 dias
}
```

Isso funciona porque, se o valor do dia for maior que a quantidade de dias do mês, [`setDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) ajusta a data automaticamente para o mês seguinte.

No exemplo acima eu coloquei `3` para o dia da semana (que equivale a quarta-feira), apenas para exemplificar. Mas no seu caso, eu sugiro que transforme o valor do `input` em número:

```
var diasem = parseInt(document.getElementById('DiaSem').value);
```

Pois isso evita [alguns problemas que podem acontecer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/478396/112052) se você não fizer esta conversão.

Comment: +1 porque foi a única resposta que levou em consideração que trabalhar com datas não será uma simples soma, pois nesse contexto é preciso considerar que os dias da semana podem terminar em outro mês.

Comment: Obrigada, eu tinha conseguido resolver o problema da pergunta depois, mas você acabou me ajudando com outras coisas!!

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa é usar o `While`. Como você sugeriu que poderia usar também.
Inicializa a variável `x` conforme a lógica que pensou validar.

```
var x = inicializaComOValorSalvo;
while(x<=31){
  console.log(x);
  x+=7;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A forma de inserir mais valores em uma somatória seria assim. o valor X +(soma) e = o valor 7.

> x+=7

```js
var x;
for (x = 4 + 1; x <= 31; x+=7){
  console.log(x);
};
```