# Localizar o índice do maior e do menor valor de um array

Tags: javascript, array

Como faço para localizar a posição do maior e menor elemento de um array em JavaScript?

Com o `reduce` eu consegui localizar o maior e o menor elemento, porém preciso pegar a posição (índice) também deles dentro do array.

Maior numero:

```
var array = ["885.9", "984.9", "444.9", "528.9", "528.9"];  
var maior_numero = array.map(Number).reduce(function(numero1, numero2) {  
  return Math.max(numero1, numero2);  
});  
        
console.log(maior_numero );
```

Menor número:

```
var array = ["88", "999", "12", "123", "230"];  
var menor_numero = array.map(Number).reduce(function(numero1, numero2) {  
  return Math.min(numero1, numero2);  
});  
        
console.log(menor_numero );
```

Comment: Acho que o `reduce` aí é meio desnecessário.  Você poderia ter feito algo como `Math.max.apply(null, ["885.9", "984.9", "444.9", "528.9", "528.9"])`

Comment: Obrigado Wallace pelo retorno, então esse código que você me ajudou está pegando o valor do elemento. Além do valor preciso pegar em qual posição ele se encontra no array, poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar um `for` simples, armazenando os índices do maior e menor número e modificando-os, se necessário.

Desse modo, você só precisará de varrer o array uma única vez.

Algo assim:

```js
function indexes(arr) {
  if (!arr.length) {
    return null;
  }
  
  let max = 0;
  let min = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const current = arr[i];
    
    if (current > arr[max]) {
      max = i;
    }
    
    if (current < arr[min]) {
      min = i;
    }
  }
  
  return { max, min };
}

console.log(indexes([3, 5, 6, 2, 1, 4])); // { max: 2, min: 4 }
console.log(indexes([1, 2])); // { max: 1, min: 0 }
console.log(indexes([])); // null
```

Não faz muito sentido você passar diretamente um *array* de *strings* para `Math.max` ou algo do tipo, já que é o tipo de dado incorreto. É pertinente converter os elementos **antes** de tentar compará-los, ou você pode acabar encontrando algumas situações bizarras, já que a comparação entre *strings* é diferente da comparação entre números.

Podemos modificar o código acima para lidar com *arrays* de *strings*:

```js
function indexes(arr) {
  if (!arr.length) {
    return null;
  }
  
  let max = 0;
  let min = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const current = parseFloat(arr[i]);
    
    if (current > parseFloat(arr[max])) {
      max = i;
    }
    
    if (current < parseFloat(arr[min])) {
      min = i;
    }
  }
  
  return { max, min };
}

console.log(indexes(["885.9", "984.9", "444.9", "528.9", "528.9"])); // { max: 1, min: 2 }
```

O JavaScript possui alguns mecanismos nativos de coerção automática de tipo, mas nem sempre fazem sentido. Para evitar problemas (que de fato ocorrerão se você não tratar os dados da forma correta — veja um exemplo [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/478396/69296)), prefira sempre realizar conversões **explícitas**. :-)

Comment: Muito obrigado Luiz Felipe, me ajudou muito! Abraço!

Answer (score 2):

Para pegar o valor maior ou menor, você pode fazer simplesmente assim:

```
var arr = ["885.9", "984.9", "444.9", "528.9", "528.9"];
var maior = Math.max.apply(null, arr)
```

Agora para pegar a posição basta usar `indexOf`

```js
var arr = ["885.9", "984.9", "444.9", "528.9", "528.9"].map(Number);
var maior = Math.max.apply(null, arr) 

console.log(maior);

console.log(arr.indexOf(maior));
```

Note que, no caso do `indexOf`, precisei chamar `map(Number)`, isso porque `indexOf` considera o tipo da variável. Como `Math.max` retorna `Number`, `indexOf` retornaria -1, por não encontrar o valor do mesmo tipo e mesmo valor (já que seu `array` é uma lista de strings).

Para não precisar converter tudo com o `map`, você poderia também usar um `toString()` no retorno de `Math.max` ou `Math.min`.

```js
var arr = ["885.9", "984.9", "444.9", "528.9", "528.9"];
var maior = Math.max.apply(null, arr) 

console.log(maior);

console.log(arr.indexOf(maior.toString()));
```

Simplificando o código para compreensão:

```
var arr = ["885.9", "984.9", "444.9", "528.9", "528.9"];

var maior = Math.max.apply(null, arr) 
var posicao_maior = arr.indexOf(maior.toString()));

var menor = Math.min.apply(null, arr) 
var posicao_menor = arr.indexOf(menor.toString()));
```

**Nota**: Para encontrar o valor de `Math.min`, a regra é a mesma do código que fiz acima com `Math.max`, basta substituir.

Comment: Muito obrigado Wallace, me ajudou muito também! Abraço!

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, outra sugestão para resolução é:

```
<script>
    var random = [2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 22, -5]; //um array aleatório
    
    // criei uma função pra encontrar o menor e maior valor do array pelo método Math.min(...nome_do_array)
    //além do valor, a função também chama o índice pelo método indexOf()


    function minimo(){

        var minimo =  Math.min(...random);
        document.getElementById('random').value = minimo;
        document.getElementById('indice').value = random.indexOf(minimo);
    }

    function maximo(){

        var maximo = Math.max(...random);
        document.getElementById('random').value = maximo;
        document.getElementById('indice').value = random.indexOf(maximo);
    }
```

Valor

```
<label for="maximo">Índice no array</label>
<input name="maximo"type="text" id="indice" value="indice" disabled>
<!-- recebe o índice indicado pelo botão abaixo -->

<br><br>

<button onclick="minimo()">Valor Mínimo</button>
<button onclick="maximo()">Valor Máximo</button><br>
<!-- botões para chamar o menor e maior valor do array, bem como seu índice, de acordo com as funções a cima -->
```

O método Math.min ou Math.max trabalha apenas com números e não irá funcionar para String. Caso vc utilize com String ele retorna NaN e, nessa pequena função e caso, o índice vai retornar -1, indicando que não foi encontrado.
Já o método indexOf() vai te retornar a posição de um determinado elemento no array, independente do tipo.

Inseri o script inline no HTML e os botões ao final para a chamada da função para ilustrar a explicação.

Sobre a manipulação do DOM, a primeira linha de cada função encontra o menor ou maior valor do array.
A segunda linha de cada função altera o valor do input com a id = random para o valor encontrado.
E a terceira linha encontra o índice do valor encontrado.

Espero ajudar alguém de alguma forma, visto que passou bastante tempo da pergunta.

Abraço à todos.