# Existe diferença entre Number e parseFloat?

Tags: javascript, números

Quando preciso transformar uma string em número no Javascript, posso usar tanto o objeto `Number` como a função  `parseFloat`.

Exemplo:

```js
var numero = "1.5";

console.log(Number(numero));
console.log(parseFloat(numero));
```

Porém eu gostaria de saber se existe algum caso onde uma outra têm comportamentos diferentes.

- Quais das duas devo preferir para converter uma string em um `Number` do tipo float?
- Existe alguma diferença entre ambas?

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a diferença de parseInt() e Number()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180248/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-de-parseint-e-number)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tem diferença em alguns casos.

Para string vazia ou contendo somente espaços, ou para `null`, `Number` retorna zero e `parseFloat` retorna `NaN`:

```js
var numero = ""; // string vazia
console.log(Number(numero)); // 0
console.log(parseFloat(numero)); // NaN

numero = "    ";
console.log(Number(numero)); // 0
console.log(parseFloat(numero)); // NaN

numero = null;
console.log(Number(numero)); // 0
console.log(parseFloat(numero)); // NaN
```

Outra diferença é no algoritmo: `parseFloat` vai lendo os caracteres da string até encontrar algo que não seja reconhecido como parte de um número, como o sinal de menos e o ponto - que é o separador decimal - além do "e" seguido de números, que é parte da notação científica, e faz o *parsing* somente da parte que conseguiu ler. `Number` não faz isso, e retorna `NaN` se a string tiver caracteres que não estão entre esses já citados:

```js
var numero = "123abc";
console.log(Number(numero)); // NaN
console.log(parseFloat(numero)); // 123

numero = "-123.45abc";
console.log(Number(numero)); // NaN
console.log(parseFloat(numero)); // -123.45

numero = "1.23e3abc"; // 1.23e3 é 1230 em notação científica
console.log(Number(numero)); // NaN
console.log(parseFloat(numero)); // 1230
```

---

Lembrando que ambos ignoram os espaços no início e fim da string (ou seja, espaços no início ou fim não caem na regra acima, de "caracteres inválidos"):

```js
var numero = "   123   ";
console.log(Number(numero)); // 123
console.log(parseFloat(numero)); // 123
```

Answer (score 5):

A diferença é sutil que pode ser notada na documentação [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat):

> The `parseFloat` function parses an argument (converting it to a string first if needed) and returns a floating point number.

Em tradução direta:

A função `parseFloat` faz o ***parse*** do argumento (convertendo-o para *string* primeiro, se necessário) e retorna um número de ponto flutuante.

Já o construtor `Number` simplesmente tenta fazer a **coerção** do valor passado para o tipo numérico. Isso não significa necessariamente fazer o *parse*, já que a coerção de tipos tem comportamento diferente de um *parse*.

O *parse*, eventualmente, poderá remover alguns caracteres que seriam inválidos ao se fazer uma simples coerção. Ao analisar a diferença dos algoritmos descritos na especificação essa diferença torna-se ainda mais evidente:

- [Especificação para o construtor `Number`.](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-number-constructor-number-value)
- [Especificação para `parseFloat`.](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-parsefloat-string)

Note que, como `Number` faz a conversão de tipos, ele pode ser substituído pelo [operador unário `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus), que tem a exata mesma função.

Vejamos alguns casos especiais (baseados [nesta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13676265/7445826)) em exemplo:

- Para qualquer entrada numérica válida, a saída será a mesma, já que esta pode ser *parseada* (por `parseFloat`) ou convertida (por `Number`) corretamente:

  ```
  parseFloat('3'); // 3
  Number('3'); // 3

  parseFloat('1.501'); // 1.501
  Number('1.501'); // 1.501

  parseFloat('1e10'); // 10000000000
  Number('1e10'); // 10000000000
  ```
- Eventualmente, o valor passado para `Number` pode não ser corretamente convertido para o tipo numérico, mas ainda pode ser *parseado* corretamente. Um exemplo disso é quando a *string* contém caracteres adicionais:

  ```
  parseFloat('1x'); // 1
  Number('1x'); // NaN
  ```
- Em relação aos literais numéricos da linguagem, `parseFloat` não consegue lidar *strings* que os representem, enquanto `Number`, sim. Isso significa que `Number` consegue converter da sintaxe literal de [binário](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numeros_e_datas#N%C3%BAmeros_Bin%C3%A1rios), [octal](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numeros_e_datas#N%C3%BAmeros_octais) e [hexadecimal](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numeros_e_datas#Numeros_hexadecimais) (assim como a decimal — já tratada anteriormente):

  ```
  parseFloat('0b10'); // 0
  Number('0b10'); // 2

  parseFloat('0o10'); // 0
  Number('0o10'); // 8

  parseFloat('0xf'); // 0
  Number('0xf');
  ```

  <sup>NO exemplo acima, `parseFloat` retorna `0` pois lê a *string* da esquerda para a direita até deixar de encontrar caracteres numéricos válidos. Como `b`, `o` e `x` são inválidos, o restante da *string* é ignorada após tais demarcações.</sup>
- Em relação aos valores literais da linguagem, `Number` faz a conversão normalmente, enquanto `parseFloat` sempre retornará `NaN`. Por exemplo, ao passarmos booleanos:

  ```
  parseFloat(true); // NaN
  Number(true); // 1

  parseFloat(false); // NaN
  Number(false); // 0
  ```

  É por isso que se você passar uma *string* vazia para `Number` `0` será retornado.

Comment: A ideia de fazer essa pergunta era ter uma resposta, justamente para ajudar naquela outra que respondemos [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/479568/localizar-o-%c3%adndice-do-maior-e-do-menor-valor-de-um-array/479572?noredirect=1#comment898519_479572), kkkkkk. +1

Comment: Boa, tinha esquecido dos números em outras bases...