# O que é o underscore ( _ ) "dentro" de um número em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, sintaxe

Percebi que posso utilizar *underscores* (`_`) entre literais numéricos em JavaScript. Por exemplo:

```js
const testA = 1_000_000_000;
console.log(testA); // => 1000000000

const testB = 1000000_0 + '_0_' + 1_0;
console.log(testB); // => "10000000_0_10"
```

A forma acima não retorna erros, mas as seguintes tentativas abaixo não funcionam:

```
const testA = 1000000_;
const testB = _100;
const testC = 1._000;
const testD = 1000000_.0;
```

Pelo que percebi, o `_` serve para facilitar a leitura dos números. De fato, ler `1_000_000_000` (1 bilhão) é bem mais fácil para se entender o número do que `1000000000`. Seria esse é o único propósito de se usar `_` nos números?

Ainda percebi em alguns testes que, dependendo da forma como se trabalha, gera-se comportamentos estranhos. Brincando com comportamentos <s>ridículos</s> inesperados do JavaScript:

```js
let c;

c = 10_000 - '10000';
console.log(c); // 0

c = 10_000 - '10_000';
console.log(c); // Achei que deveria sair 0, mas retorna NaN
```

Pelo visto, só posso utilizar o `_` em números de fato.

Essa *feature* é nova no JavaScript? Ela tem nome? Pois nunca tinha visto seu uso em lugar algum...

Comment: A linguagem definiu assim (es2021). O `_` é um separador válido de literais numéricos. https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-NumericLiteralSeparator

Comment: ah que que é algo novo. se fosse feature antiga, teria ficado preocupado.

Comment: Kkkkk. preocupado em que sentido?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chama-se *numeric separator* ou, em português, separador numérico. Foi estandardizado no ECMAScript 2021. Veja o [repositório](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-numeric-separator) com a proposta e discussões. E a seção [§ 12.8.3](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-literals-numeric-literals) da especificação.

É um recurso que extende a notação para **literais numéricos** em JavaScript, o que inclui valores do tipo [`number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Number) em representação numérica decimal (a usual), binária, octal e hexadecimal. Também pode ser utilizado no tipo numérico [`bigint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/BigInt). O objetivo é meramente estético para facilitar a leitura, que é certamente beneficiada em longas sequências numéricas.

Alguns exemplos com o tipo numérico:

```
0b111_111; // Binário.     Avalia para: 63
0o777_777; // Octal.       Avalia para: 262143
1_000_000; // Decimal.     Avalia para: 1000000
0xfff_fff; // Hexadecimal. Avalia para: 16777215
```

E com *bigint* (denotados por `n` ao final):

```
1000000n; // Ou:
1_000_000n;
```

O local em que o *underscore* será posicionado não é definido. Você pode colocá-lo entre quaisquer dígitos do literal numérico. No entanto, existem três exceções notáveis:

- Não podem haver dois *underscores* seguidos.
- Não pode estar adjacente ao caractere (`b` para binário, `o` para octal e `x` para hexadecimal) que denota número com base numérica literal explícita.
- Não pode estar adjacente ao separador decimal (`.`).
- Não pode estar adjacente ao sufixo `n`, que denota *bigints* literais.

Desse modo, os seguintes causam erro de sintaxe:

```
1__000; // SyntaxError (dois underscores seguidos)
0b_111; // SyntaxError (adjacente ao prefixo de base binária)
0o_777; // SyntaxError (adjacente ao prefixo de base octal)
0x_fff; // SyntaxError (adjacente ao prefixo de base hexadecimal)
12._34; // SyntaxError (adjacente ao separador decimal)
1000_n; // SyntaxError (adjacente ao sufixo de bigint literal)
```

<sup>A definição formal da sintaxe pode ser consultada [aqui](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-literals-numeric-literals). Consulte a [tabela de compatibilidade](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_grammar_numeric_separators) para saber quais navegadores suportam sem transpilação.</sup>

---

#### Sobre conversões

Vale lembrar que os *numeric separators* são um recurso meramente sintático da linguagem. Nada muda no quesito de como os números são representados internamente, como são convertidos (de string para número, por exemplo) e/ou *parseados*.

Por conta disso, você não pode fazer isto e esperar que dê certo:

```
parseInt('1_000', 10); //-> 1
```

<sup><sup>[Mais informações.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/479586/69296)</sup></sup>

E nem isto:

```
Number('1_000'); //-> NaN
```

Em tese, o construtor `Number` tenta "converter" um valor para o tipo numérico. Mas o JavaScript não entende strings com o separador numérico como números válidos. Por isso `NaN` é retornado na expressão abaixo:

```
10_000 - '10_000'; //-> `NaN`
```

- A expressão acima avalia para `NaN` porque o operador `-` tenta converter os dois operandos para o tipo numérico (caso não estejam). Internamente, um algoritmo similar ao construtor `Number` é utilizado. Desse modo, como `Number('10_000')` é `NaN`, `10_000 - NaN` só pode ser `NaN`. Mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/436573/69296).
- Funciona no outro exemplo da pergunta (`10_000 - '10000'`) porque o JavaScript consegue converter a string `10000` para número. Já a string `'10_000'`, como vimos acima, não é "entendida" pelo algoritmo de conversão – ainda bem.

Em suma, entenda a proposta de separadores numéricas, que hoje já faz parte da linguagem, como algo *exclusivo* para o aspecto do código, isto é, sua sintaxe. Não é algo que trouxe nenhuma "alteração" muito profunda...

Answer (score 6):

É algo novo em JS e deve fazer parte da ES2021 já sendo suportado por alguns *engines*. Veja a [proposta de separador numérico (*numeric separator*)](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-numeric-separator).

É uma forma para dar mais legibilidade para literais numéricos. Então pode usar o símbolo de *underscore* em quaisquer partes de um número para "agrupar" dígitos. Em geral será usado como separador de milhar ou em alguns casos de forma mais específica, inclusive quando usa hexadecimal e principalmente binário pode ser bem útil para separar as partes da informação. É só para isto mesmo.

O caractere é completamente ignorado depois de compilado. Só não faz sentido usar onde não separa partes do número, como o início, fim e ele repetido..

```
let budget = 1_000_000_000_000;
let nibbles = 0b1010_0001_1000_0101;
let message = 0xA0_B0_C0;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/LiteralNotations.js).