# Ordenar string por ordem crescente de acordo com o valor numérico

Tags: javascript

Tenho de inserir números e ordenar por ordem crescente para apresentar o resultado. Mas não estou a conseguir ordenar corretamente. Eis o que acontece:

Se inserir por exemplo `76,3,15,35` retorna ordenado na seguinte forma: `15,3,35,76`.

```js
// ordenar por ordem crescente os numeros inseridos.

const input1 = document.querySelector(".input1");
const btnConvert = document.querySelector(".btn-converter");

function sortNumbers(inputText) {
  let numArray = inputText.split(",");
  numArray.sort();

  document.getElementById("h").innerText = (` ${ numArray} `); 
  console.log(numArray)

  return  numArray;
}


btnConvert.addEventListener('click', function () {
  sortNumbers(input1.value);

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Modelo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <section class="container">
      <h1>Exercícios</h1>

      <label class="label"
        >INSERIR NÚMEROS 
        <input type="text"  class="input1" />
      </label>
      

      <button class="btn btn-converter">ORDENAR POR ORDEM CRESCENTE</button>

     
      <h2 class="total" id="h"></h2>
    </section>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Certo, obrigada :) No entanto iria obrigar-me a ter sempre os dois digitos e não era bem o que pretendia. além disso, se por algum motivo estranho eu colocasse 015,p.e, ele continuaria a ordenar da mesma forma. Mas obrigada pela dica na mesma :)

Comment: Ana, colocar o zero à esquerda é gambiarra, esqueça isso. É mais simples converter para número, pois aí funciona para quaisquer valores (como indicado nas respostas abaixo)

Comment: certo, obrigada :)

Comment: @hkotsubo, colocar zero a esquerda de hora com um digito é gambiarra também?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo No caso de horário, colocar o zero à esquerda é questão de formatação/apresentação, é completamente diferente do que está sendo feito aqui. Colocar um zero à esquerda na string só pra forçar uma ordenação correta eu considero gambiarra, ainda mais quando há uma solução mais simples e limpa (converter as strings pra número). Problemas diferentes, soluções diferentes :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo, seu entendimento, repare que a pergunta é: Ordenar string por ordem crescente javascript, eu li STRING ou preciso atualizar meu oculos?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Mas estamos ordenando strings. Só que o critério de ordenação é usar o **valor numérico que a string representa**, por isso que eu acho melhor converter para número em vez de adicionar zeros à esquerda. Até porque adicionar zeros é limitado (se a string for `'76,03,123456,35'`, por exemplo, já não funciona, vc teria que adicionar mais zeros em cada número pra funcionar - algo como `'000076,000003,123456,000035'`). E nem vou entrar no mérito que `'03'` é uma **string** diferente de `'3'`...

Comment: @hkotsubo, tens razão, transformar em números para ordenar é a melhor solução, colocar zeros daria uma volta tremenda, pegar o comprimento do maior elemento do array, colocar tantos zeros quantos necessários, ordenar e voltar aos elementos iniciais para apresentação.  Mas seria um bom exercicio né não?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando você faz o `split`, [o resultado é um array de strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Return_value).

Só que strings são comparadas lexicograficamente, ou seja, leva-se em conta os caracteres dela para definir qual é "maior" ou "menor". Mesmo que esses caracteres sejam dígitos, o valor numérico que eles representam não é levado em conta na ordenação. Sendo assim, a string `'15'` é "menor" que a string `'3'` (no sentido de que, em uma ordenação, a string `'15'` é colocada antes da string `'3'`).

```js
console.log('15' < '3'); // true
```

Por isso que a string `'15'` ficou antes da string `'3'`.
Para entender melhor porque é assim, eu sugiro que [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/440496/112052).

---

De qualquer forma, se quer levar em conta o valor numérico que as strings representam, eu sugiro que as transformem em números:

```
numArray.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a) - parseInt(b));
```

Eu usei [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), pois assim deixo claro que estou convertendo as strings em números. E a ideia da função de *callback* é que ela retorne um número negativo se `a` deve vir antes de `b` na ordenação, um número positivo se `a` deve vir depois, ou zero se tanto faz. Por isso que estou subtraindo os valores (pois se o valor de `a` for menor que `b`, o resultado será negativo, indicando que `a` deve vir antes na ordenação).

Claro que o código da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/483594/112052) também funciona, mas é porque o JavaScript faz coerção automática de tipos em muitos casos (se eu "subtraio" 2 strings e elas contém somente dígitos, a conversão para número é feita automaticamente).

Mas eu prefiro ser explícito e converter tudo para número antes de fazer as operações. Sei que para este caso específico funciona, mas [nem sempre é assim](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat), ainda mais se você [misturar números e strings](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/478396/112052) - então crie desde já este hábito de converter para os tipos adequados para só depois fazer as operações que precisa.

---

Lembrando que `parseInt` só trabalha com números inteiros. Se quiser considerar também números com casas decimais (desde que o separador seja o ponto), pode usar [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat). Ex:

```js
let s = '20,10.5,47.2,3';
let array = s.split(',');
array.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b));
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Execelente observacao. Esqueci de mencionar a importancia de converter antes de fazer a operacao necessaria afim de evitar problemas com o comportamento "esquisito" do JS

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigada pela dica :)

Comment: @CmteCardeal Nesse caso específico não é tão problemático assim porque é um "ambiente controlado" e sabemos que funcionaria "em todos os casos". Mas como regra geral, eu sempre prefiro converter :-)

Answer (score 4):

Você poderia usar `numArray.sort((a,b) => {return a - b});` para ordernar e não ter esse problema. Você ordena fazendo uma **comparação** de valores usando a função `(a,b) => {return a - b}`, onde:

- Se o retorno for menor que 0, então `b` é maior que `a`, logo `a` vem primeiro que `b`;
- Se o retorno for maior que 0, então `b` é menor que `a`, logo `b` vem primeiro que `a`;
- Se o retorno for igual a 0, então `b` é igual a `a`;

Veja como fica:

```js
// ordenar por ordem crescente os numeros inseridos.

const input1 = document.querySelector(".input1");
const btnConvert = document.querySelector(".btn-converter");

function sortNumbers(inputText) {
  let numArray = inputText.split(",");
  numArray.sort((a,b) => {return a - b});

  document.getElementById("h").innerText = (` ${ numArray} `); 
  console.log(numArray)

  return  numArray;
}


btnConvert.addEventListener('click', function () {
  sortNumbers(input1.value);

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Modelo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <section class="container">
      <h1>Exercícios</h1>

      <label class="label"
        >INSERIR NÚMEROS 
        <input type="text"  class="input1" />
      </label>
      

      <button class="btn btn-converter">ORDENAR POR ORDEM CRESCENTE</button>

     
      <h2 class="total" id="h"></h2>
    </section>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Seria essa resposta para `76,3,15,35`:

```
[
  "3",
  "15",
  "35",
  "76"
]
```

---

#### DICA

Para deixar na ordem decrescente, basta inverter o retorno da função de comparação:

```
numArray.sort((a,b) => {return b - a});
```

Comment: Muito obrigada :) tinha tentado fazer dessa forma, mas inventei e afinal era simples. obrigada, ficou resolvido :)