# Como deixar um número com apenas duas casas decimais sem arredondar

Tags: javascript

O método `toFixed(2)` deixa o número com duas casas decimais, mas quando a terceira casa decimal é 5, ele arredonda pra cima e eu gostaria que arredondasse pra baixo. Existe alguma maneira?

Exemplo:

```
let num = 10.125
num = num.toFixed(2); //num = 10.13
```

Nesse caso o resultado que eu preciso é `num = 10.12`.

Comment: Na verdade se pegar o número sem arrendondar?

Answer (score 4):

Se a ideia é deixar somente 2 casas decimais, basta fazer alguns cálculos simples:

- primeiro você multiplica por 100, o resultado será `1012.5`
- depois arredonda para baixo, resultando em `1012`
- por fim, divide por 100, o resultado será `10.12`

```js
let num = 10.125;
num = Math.floor(num * 100) / 100;

console.log(num); // 10.12
```

De forma geral, se você quer manter apenas N casas decimais, basta fazer o processo acima para 10<sup>N</sup>. Ou seja, dá para generalizar o código acima:

```js
function manterCasas(num, casas) {
    let n = Math.pow(10, casas);
    return Math.floor(num * n) / n;
}

let num = 10.125;

console.log(manterCasas(num, 2)); // 10.12
console.log(manterCasas(num, 1)); // 10.1
```

---

Só tem um detalhe: [`toFixed` retorna uma **string**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed#Return_value), enquanto os códigos acima retornam um número. Claro que ao imprimir, ambos são mostrados da mesma forma, mas não ficou claro qual você quer (já que dependendo do que você vai fazer com esses dados depois, [pode dar diferença](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/478396/112052)).

Mas enfim, se quiser uma string, basta pegar o resultado e chamar `.toString()` (não precisaria mais de `toFixed` pois o valor já está com a quantidade desejada de casas decimais):

```js
let num = 10.125;

// se quiser o resultado como uma string
let numString = (Math.floor(num * 100) / 100).toString();

console.log(numString);
```

Answer (score 3):

Podes usar o `toFixed` com decimais a mais e depois cortar o último valor...

```js
const toNotRoundedFixed = (nr, fixed) => nr.toFixed(fixed + 3).slice(0, -3)

const num = 10.125
console.log(num.toFixed(2)) // 10.13
console.log(toNotRoundedFixed(num, 2)) // 10.12
```