# Como aumentar e diminuir a velocidade de um vídeo?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Gostaria de saber qual é a forma de diminuir e aumentar a velocidade do vídeo pois gostaria de oferecer essa opção ao usuário que utiliza a plataforma!

Este é o único problema que não encontrei uma solução, todas as outras ferramentas funcionam super bem por exemplo de volume, a única coisa que gostaria de fazer é essa alteração de velocidade.

Não sei como faria para aumentar e diminuir a velocidade do vídeo, mas bem, esta é minha ideia:

```
<video id="meuVideo"><!--esse é o meu vídeo--></video>
<input type="range" id="velocidade"><!--aqui ficaria o controle de velocidade-->
```

Minha ideia seria pegar o `value` do `input` e convertê-lo na velocidade do vídeo, não sei se a velocidade do vídeo é igual o controle de volume, mas é isso que eu quero. Alguém poderia me ajudar/explicar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para controlar a velocidade de um vídeo sendo exibido na tag [`<video>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video), você pode utilizar a propriedade [`playbackRate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/playbackRate).

O padrão dessa propriedade é `1`. Desse modo, o valor `1.5` representaria 150% da velocidade e `0.5`, 50%, por exemplo. Somente valores positivos têm efeito visual. Um valor negativo, por exemplo, não faria com que o vídeo fosse exibido no sentido inverso.

---

Em relação ao [`<input type="range">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/range), você pode utilizar os atributos `max`, `min` e `step`, se necessário, para controlar o comportamento. Se utilizar o intervalo entre `1` e `200`, por exemplo, precisará dividir o valor obtido por 100 para adequá-lo ao intervalo esperado por `playbackRate`. Assim:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#velocidade');

input.addEventListener('change', function() {
  const rate = parseInt(this.value, 10) / 100; // Dividir por 100 para ficar no range desejado
  console.log(rate);
});
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="200" value="100" id="velocidade" />
```

Utilizei o [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) porque a propriedade `value` de qualquer *input* **sempre** retorna uma string. Embora o JavaScript faça a coerção para de tipos você nesse caso, o comportamento [nem sempre é previsível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/478396/69296). Desse modo, prefira *sempre* ser explícito quanto às conversões de tipo em JavaScript. Uma outra opção seria utilizar a propriedade `valueAsNumber`.

Em seguida basta atribuir o valor obtido à propriedade do video dentro do *handler* do *event listener*. Mais ou menos assim:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#velocidade');
const video = document.querySelector('#meuVideo');

input.addEventListener('change', function() {
  const rate = parseInt(this.value, 10) / 100;
  video.playbackRate = rate;
});
```