# Tentativa de fazer um site de sorteios

Tags: javascript

Eu estava tentando fazer um site de sorteio, onde determina os valores mínimos e máximos e então é feito um sorteio, retornando para você um valor entre um desses números. Aqui está o html:

```js
function sorteio() {
  const min = document.getElementById('minimo').value
  const max = document.getElementById('maximo').value
  const sorte = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = sorte
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sorteador</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <input type="number" id="minimo"><br><br>
  <input type="number" id="maximo"><br><br>
  <button onclick="sorteio()">Sorteio</button>
  <h1 id="resultado"></h1>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Quando clico no botão, ele fica retornado números que não estão dentro do intervalo predefinido. Já tentei de tudo, mas não consigo resolver o problema.

Comment: O problema é que você não está utilizando valores numéricos na sua expressão que atribui à `sorte`, mas sim strings (retornadas pela propriedade `value`). A **[resposta linkada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/478394/69296)** explica como e porque é importante realizar conversões ao tipo esperado no JavaScript. O curioso é que parece ser o mesmo código que você está tentando fazer, então a resposta será provavelmente de grande ajuda. :)

Comment: CARACA MLK, TMJ VEI, PORRA BRABO DEMAIS