# Qual a relação do operador "+" com o método "valueOf()" em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, operadores, conversão-de-tipo

Estou com uma dúvida em relação ao operador `+`.

[Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/436573/95771) sobre o operador, foi dito o seguinte:

> O `+` também pode fazer o papel de um **operador binário**. Nesse
> caso, opera sobre **dois** valores. Nesse sentido, o `+` pode ter duas
> funções diferentes, a depender do tipo dos dois operandos:
>
> - Realizar a **soma** de dois valores (adição); ou:
> - Realizar a **concatenação** de duas strings.
>
> ...
>
> - Primeiro, o operador converte os dois operandos a valores primitivos. Após isso, irá seguir a um dos dois modos:
>
>   1. **Modo string**: Se qualquer um dos dois operandos for uma string, o outro operando será convertido ao tipo `string`
>      correspondente. Os dois valores serão posteriormente concatenados e
>      retornados como string.
>   2. **Modo numérico**: Caso contrário (nenhum dos operandos é string), converterá ambos os operadores ao tipo `number`. Os dois
>      valores serão posteriormente somados e retornados como número.

Eu percebi alguns comportamentos. O operador `+` "parece" que invoca a função `valueOf` sempre que esta está presente dentro de um objeto. Vejam abaixo:

```js
function User() {
  return {
    valueOf: () => 'Brendam'
  }
}

const result = new User() + new User()

console.log(result)
```

Como visto acima, o `+` fez algo a mais do que eu esperava. Mas não acabou por ai. O mesmo comportamento acontece se tentarmos usar este operado para converter um objeto literal que tenha o mesmo método, porém que retorne um **número**. Se o mesmo retornar uma string, recebemos `NaN` como resultado:

```js
let obj = {
  valueOf: function() {
    return 'Brendam'
  }
}

let obj2 = {
  valueOf: function() {
    return 10;
  }
};

console.log(+obj)  // NaN
console.log(+obj2) // 10
```

Confesso que fiquei muito confuso com o uso deste operador:

- Por que `+` invoca o `valueOf`? Qual a relação entre eles?
- Só este operador faz isso? Ou o mesmo comportamento se repete para algum outro operador?

Comment: coisas bizarras do `javascript`, não consigo imagiar `new User() + new User()` em java, c, c++ ou c# por exemplo  :D

Comment: @RicardoPontual seria tão simples se lançasse só uma exceçãozinha...

Comment: pois é, o javascript engana a gente, não da erro em muitas situações, mas retorna algo difícil de entender

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse é um comportamento que se deve à natureza de coerções típicas do JavaScript. É uma linguagem que historicamente se baseia na conversão automática de tipos, então existem vários mecanismos para que isso seja feito.

No caso do `+` (tanto binário quanto unário) e a maioria dos outros operadores que realizam a conversão ao tipo esperado, há uma série de etapas a serem tomadas para que o *runtime* decida *como* converter ao valor adequado.

Abaixo exploraremos como funciona a conversão de objetos a um primitivo esperado. No caso desta resposta, o resultado esperado é `number`, mas pode variar a depender do operador que se utiliza.

No final das contas, as etapas são muito similares. Basta seguir o algoritmo descrito na *spec*.

#### Por que `+` invoca o `valueOf`? Qual a relação entre eles?

Por que é design da linguagem.

- No caso do unário `+`, a especificação (entre as muitas etapas listadas) aplica a operação abstrata [`ToNumber`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-tonumber) que, em caso de objetos (isto é, valores nos quais o `valueOf` é levado em conta), chama [`ToPrimitive`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-toprimitive), que chama [`OrdinaryToPrimitive`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-ordinarytoprimitive), que, por fim, chama o método `valueOf` em objetos.
- No caso do binário `+`, que opera no "modo string" ou "modo numérico", pode ocorrer isto:

  1. No modo string, chama-se a operação abstrata [`ToString`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-tostring) aos operandos. Seguindo para objetos, invoca-se `ToPrimitive` que, como já vimos acima, invocará `OrdinaryToPrimitive`.
  2. No modo numérico, chama-se a operação abstrata [`ToNumeric`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-tonumeric), de modo que ocorrem etapas similares ao que ocorreu no unário, só que para os dois argumentos.

Note, no algoritmo de `OrdinaryToPrimitive`, que ele primeiro tenta invocar `valueOf` e, se não disponível, possui *fallback* ao `toString`. Isso já explica o comportamento demonstrado na pergunta.

É algo muito sutil e pouco usado (muita gente nem sabe que o `valueOf` existe), por isso não se vê muito sobre isso.

Eu não esperaria alguém (com exceção, talvez, de criadores de bibliotecas) utilizando esse mecanismo para desenvolver código no dia a dia. É algo extremamente obscuro.

E claro, o JavaScript tinha que complicar mais um pouco. Na maioria das conversões de tipos, se houver um método definido por [`@@toPrimitive`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive) (isso é um *well known symbol*) no objeto ao qual deseja se realizar a conversão, este será utilizado. Basicamente, antes de se invocar a operação abstrata `OrdinaryToPrimitive`, a implementação tenta chamar o método definido por esse *well known symbol*. No caso dele ser `undefined`, utiliza-se `OrdinaryToPrimitive` como *fallback*.

Para entender, pense no `@@toPrimitive` como uma operação de conversão *não ordinária*. No caso dele não existir, utiliza-se a conversão *ordinária*.

---

#### Só o operador `+` faz isso? Ou o mesmo se repete para algum outro?

Esse comportamento *não* é exclusivo do `+`.

Como o JavaScript é uma linguagem que faz diversos tipos de coerção típicas. Portanto, a maioria dos operadores que faz coerção de tipos automaticamente está "suscetível" ao método `valueOf`. Isso acontece porque as diversas conversões que o JavaScript faz culminam na operação abstrata `OrdinaryToPrimitive` que, como já vimos acima, acaba invocando o `valueOf`.

Por padrão, chama-se o `valueOf`. Caso este não exista, invoca-se `toString`. No caso de coerções que visam uma conversão ao tipo string, o `toString` é chamado antes do `valueOf`, se este existir. O `@@toPrimitive` é sempre priorizado, se existir.

---

Sobre o último tópico da pergunta, o resultado é diferente porque, no primeiro caso, o `+` foi utilizado como operador binário que efetua concatenação. Já no segundo exemplo, o `+` foi utilizado como operador unário, de modo a realizar a conversão ao tipo `number`.