# Gostaria de saber como coloco esse formulário para ler apenas números assim [1,70] e [66.2]

Tags: javascript

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
function CalcularIMC(){
    let formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");


    let altura = +formulario.altura.value;
    let peso = +formulario.peso.value;

    var imc = (altura * altura)/peso;


    formulario.IMC.value = imc.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<form id="formulario">
  <legend>Seu IMC</legend>
  <div class="form=group">
    <label for="altura">Altura:</label>
    <input type="text" name="altura" placeholder="sua altura Ex: 1,80" maxlength="4" minlength="4">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group1">
    <label for="peso">Peso:</label>
    <input type="text" name="peso" placeholder="Seu peso Ex: 69,02" minlength="4" maxlength="4">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group2">
    <label for="IMC">IMC:</label>
    <input type="text" name="IMC" disabled="disabled">

  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, o melhor a se fazer é alterar os seus **type="text"** para **type="number"**. Essa alteração fará primeiro com que seu *input* não aceite caracteres alfabéticos ou especiais, e em segundo lugar entregara um retorno numérico padrão a sua requisição, isso significa que quando consultar o valor do campo preenchido com 1,71 ele retornará 1.71 e seu calculo não será afetado.

O código dos inputs de entrada ficaria assim:

```
<input type="number" name="altura" placeholder="sua altura Ex: 1,80" maxlength="4" minlength="4">

<input type="number" name="peso" placeholder="Seu peso Ex: 69,02" minlength="4" maxlength="4">
```

Veja mais configurações sobre input number aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Comment: Obrigado funcionou

Answer (score 0):

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/448743/112052) sugeriu mudar os campos para [`input type="number"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number), que *aparentemente* resolve o problema. Não se esqueça de colocar o [`step`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#step), para permitir valores com casas decimais.

No exemplo abaixo, usei `step="0.01"` para permitir duas casas decimais (se quiser apenas uma casa decimal, use `step="0.1"`):

```js
function calcularIMC(){
    let formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");

    let altura = parseFloat(formulario.altura.value);
    let peso = parseFloat(formulario.peso.value);
    if (isNaN(altura) || isNaN(peso) || peso <= 0 || altura <= 0) {
        alert('peso e altura devem ser números positivos');
        return;
    }

    let imc = peso / (altura * altura);
    formulario.IMC.value = imc.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<form id="formulario">
  <legend>Seu IMC</legend>
  <div class="form=group">
    <label for="altura">Altura:</label>
    <input type="number" name="altura" placeholder="sua altura Ex: 1,80" maxlength="4" minlength="4" step="0.01">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group1">
    <label for="peso">Peso:</label>
    <input type="number" name="peso" placeholder="Seu peso Ex: 69,02" minlength="4" maxlength="4" step="0.01">
  </div>

  <input type="button" value="calcular" onclick="calcularIMC()">

  <div class="form-group2">
    <label for="IMC">IMC:</label>
    <input type="text" name="IMC" disabled="disabled">
  </div>
</form>
```

Mas tem um detalhe: em um campo `input type="number"`, o separador de casas decimais pode variar conforme a configuração do *locale* do browser ou do [atributo `lang`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang), então não é garantido que será sempre vírgula.

Além disso, o fato do número ser mostrado com vírgula e não ponto é uma mera questão visual, pois o seu valor sempre será com ponto. O que você pode controlar é a apresentação (a forma como o valor é mostrado), ainda sim não é garantido que funcione igual em todos os browsers. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
function mostrar(){
    let formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");

    console.log('peso1', formulario.peso1.value);
    console.log('peso2', formulario.peso2.value);
}
```

```html
<form id="formulario">
    Com ponto (ou não): <input type="number" lang="en" name="peso1" step="0.01">
    <br>Com vírgula:<input type="number" lang="pt" name="peso2" step="0.01">

    <input type="button" value="mostrar valores" onclick="mostrar()">
</form>
```

Se você rodar o exemplo acima no Firefox, o primeiro `input` mostrará o número usando o ponto como separador decimal, e o segundo mostrará a vírgula. Isso porque cada campo está usando a configuração relativa ao *locale*, indicado pelo atributo `lang`.

Já no Chrome, ambos serão mostrados da mesma forma (ou ambos com ponto, ou ambos com vírgula, dependendo das configurações de idioma que estiverem setadas).

Além disso, se eu digitar manualmente `1.43` no segundo campo, o Chrome consegue converter o valor corretamente para `1.43`, enquanto no Firefox o valor não é reconhecido (digite manualmente e clique no botão "mostrar valores").

Curiosamente, se no Firefox eu digitar `1,43` no primeiro campo, ele pega corretamente o valor.

Independente dessa bagunça de aceitar ou não determinados valores, o `console.log` sempre mostrará o valor com ponto.

---

Enfim, se o problema é apenas uma questão de visualização, você pode usar `lang="pt"`, que força o uso de vírgula em alguns browsers, mas sabendo que também pode ou não aceitar ponto em outros.

Mas se você quer aceitar que o usuário digite ponto ou vírgula, outra opção é manter o campo como `input type="text"` e ter uma função que converte ambos os casos para número. Algo assim:

```
function converter(valor) {
    return parseFloat(valor.replace(',', '.'));
}
```

Ou seja, se tiver vírgula, troca para ponto e faz a conversão. Se tiver ponto, o `replace` não altera a string, e faz a conversão.

Repare também que usei [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) para converter para número. Usar o `+` na frente do valor também "funciona", mas há casos em que eles não dão o mesmo resultado ([veja aqui alguns exemplos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/410229/112052) <- este link fala de `parseInt`, mas a ideia geral é a mesma).

Um caso que dá diferença é quando a string é vazia (ou seja, quando o campo não foi preenchido). `parseFloat('')` retorna [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) (*not a number*) enquanto `+''` retorna `0`. Você quer que use o valor zero se não for preenchido nada? (mesmo que queira, de qualquer forma teria que validar como eu fiz acima, caso contrário você fará uma divisão por zero - e repare também que o cálculo estava errado, é o peso que é dividido pelo quadrado da altura, não o contrário).

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!!