# Dúvida básica sobre função diff assoc - PHP

Tags: php, array-associativo

Praticando e relembrando as funções em *PHP*, encontrei uma pequena dúvida na função `array_diff_assoc`.

Exemplo do site:

> Exemplo #2 Exemplo da função `array_diff_assoc()`
>
> Dois valores dos pares chave => valor são considerados iguais somente
>   se `(String) $elem1 === (String) $elem2` . Em outras palavras, uma
>   checagem estrita de string é feita para que representações de `String`
>   sejam as mesmas.

Alguém saberia me dizer por quais motivos o número 2 não aparece na impressão do `Array`, se os tipos não são os mesmo?

```
<?php
$array1 = array(0, 1, 2);
$array2 = array("00", "01", "2");
$result = array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Alguém saberia me dizer por quais motivos o número 2 não aparece na
> impressão do Array, se os tipos não são os mesmo?

O número 2 não aparece no seu `print_r` justamente por conta do cast (String) que o método realiza antes de fazer a comparação:

> Dois valores dos pares chave => valor são considerados iguais somente se (String) $elem1 === (String) $elem2 . Em outras palavras, uma checagem estrita de String é feita para que representações de String sejam as mesmas.

Simplificando para você, este método faz a comparação de dois `Arrays` obtendo seus valores por index do `Array` e tranformando-os em `String` antes de fazer a comparação, ou seja, para melhorar seu entendimento ao chamar `array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2);` ele faz as 3 seguintes etapas:

```
$array1[0] em seu cast para String é igual(em tipo e valor ===) à $array2[0] ? Se não, vamos exibí-lo,
$array1[1] em seu cast para String é igual(em tipo e valor ===) à $array2[1] ? Se não, vamos exibí-lo,
$array1[2] em seu cast para String é igual(em tipo e valor ===) à $array2[2] ? Se não, vamos exibí-lo.
```

No ultimo caso, a conversão de valor 2(do $array1) para String e a o valor 2(do $array2) são iguais em valor e tipagem, logo, ele não é exibito no seu `print_r`.

Vale lembrar que o uso do `array_diff_assoc()` também checa a igualdade do índice de seu `Array`.

---

**@edit:**

Em contato com a equipe do PHP, obtivemos a seguinte resposta:

> You're ignoring the "`(string)`" in the description...
>
> `(string) $elem1` means to cast the value of `$elem1` to a `string`.
>
> `(string) $elem2` means to cast the value of `$elem2` to a `string`.
>
> `===` means to perform a strict comparison between the left and right values.
>
> So `(string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2` means to perform a strict comparison between the left, which is the value of `$elem1` cast to a `string`, and the right, which is the value of `$elem2` cast to a `string`.
>
> If `$elem1` is `2` and `$elem2` is `"2"` then `(string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2`
>
> is the same as `(string) 2 === (string) "2"`
>
> is the same as `"2" === "2"`
>
> **which is true**.
>
> `array_diff_assoc` will compare the values in multiple arrays according to their keys, and return the ones in the first array that are not present in the other arrays. Since the comparison was true for `$array1`'s `2=>2` entry, `array_diff_assoc` considers that the value `2` was present in the second array and so it will not include it in the return value.
>
> **So no, it should not return** `2`.

***Em tradução livre:***

> Você está ignorando o "`(string)`" na descrição ...
>
> `(string) $elem1` significa converter o valor de `$elem1` para uma `string`.
>
> `(string) $elem2` significa converter o valor de `$elem2` para uma `string`.
>
> `===` significa realizar uma comparação estrita entre os valores da esquerda e da direita.
>
> Então, `(string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2` significa executar uma comparação estrita entre a esquerda, que é o valor de `$elem1` convertido em uma `string`, e a direita, que é a valor de `$elem2` convertido em uma `string`.
>
> Se `$elem1` for `2` e `$elem2` for `"2"` então `(string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2`
>
> é o mesmo que `(string) 2 === (string) "2"`
>
> é o mesmo que `"2" === "2"`
>
> **que é verdade**.
>
> `array_diff_assoc` irá comparar os valores em múltiplos *arrays* de acordo com suas chaves, e retornará aqueles no primeiro *array* que não estão presentes nos outros *arrays*. Como a comparação era verdadeira para a entrada `2 => 2` do `$array1`, o `array_diff_assoc` considera que o valor `2` estava presente no segundo *array* e por isso não o incluirá no valor de retorno.
>
> **Então não, não deve retornar** `2`.

Por [requinix@php.net](http://requinix@php.net) em resposta a [@LipESprY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/45810/lipespry).

Comment: Acabei de receber uma resposta dos desenvolvedores do PHP que explica exatamente isso. Se achar interessante, posso reforçar sua resposta adicionando tal explicação...

Comment: Claro Lip, quanto mais explicativo, melhor para todos!

Comment: Muito obrigado @AndréFilipe me ajudou muito!!!!

Comment: Feito! @LuizAugusto veja a parte editada.

Comment: Show de bola pessoal!

Answer (score 5):

Porque PHP é uma linguagem de [tipagem fraca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101) e tenta interpretar tudo o que dá como o mesmo tipo, então `2` é o mesmo que `"2"`. Se isto te incomoda procure uma linguagem de tipagem forte. As regras do PHP são esquisitas e quando tem um `0` na frente ele interpreta diferente. Por isso nesta linguagem nunca pode confiar no dado.

Mais pode ser visto em [Por que no PHP a expressão "2 + '6 maçãs'" é igual a 8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80767/101).